# Comparing NumPy arrays so that NaNs compare equal

Tags: python, numpy, comparison, nan

Is there an idiomatic way to compare two NumPy arrays that would treat NaNs as being equal to each other (but not equal to anything *other* than a NaN).

For example, I want the following two arrays to compare equal:

```
np.array([1.0, np.NAN, 2.0])
np.array([1.0, np.NAN, 2.0])
```

and the following two arrays to compare unequal:

```
np.array([1.0, np.NAN, 2.0])
np.array([1.0, 0.0, 2.0])
```

I am looking for a method that would produce a scalar Boolean outcome.

The following would do it:

```
np.all((a == b) | (np.isnan(a) & np.isnan(b)))
```

but it's clunky and creates all those intermediate arrays.

Is there a way that's easier on the eye and makes better use of memory?

P.S. If it helps, the arrays are known to have the same shape and dtype.

Comment: @DanielRoseman: I understand that. I've got two methods of producing a NumPy array, and I need to know whether they've produced identical arrays.

Comment: You've ruled out one answer from [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10710328/577088); are you ruling out the other two as well?

Comment: @senderle: Thanks for the pointer. That question didn't show up in my search. However, all of those suggestions are either verbose or make very poor use of memory (or both). :-(

Comment: @aix, I agree :) Just wanted to draw your attention to it. The `testing.assert_equal` approach is almost good, except that it presumably fails if `__debug__` is False!

Comment: If you're using the current git tip for numpy, there's an [`numpy.isclose` function](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/core/numeric.py#L2039) that takes an `equal_nan` keyword argument (which  defaults to `False` for compatibility).  It's not terribly memory-friendly, though.

Comment: If it weren't for numbers which compare equal but have different binary representations (0.0 and -0.0, e.g.) then memoryview(a0) == memoryview(a1) would do it..

Comment: @DSM: Thank you for this. It might actually fit the bill for my use case. Would you mind writing it up as an answer?

Comment: Have you looked at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710328/comparing-numpy-arrays-containing-nan/10710390

Comment: @JoshAdel: Yes. Please see my earlier comment addressed to senderle.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [comparing numpy arrays containing NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710328/comparing-numpy-arrays-containing-nan)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you really care about memory use (e.g. have very large arrays), then you should use numexpr and the following expression will work for you:

```
np.all(numexpr.evaluate('(a==b)|((a!=a)&(b!=b))'))
```

I've tested it on very big arrays with length of 3e8, and the code has the same performance on my machine as

```
np.all(a==b)
```

and uses the same amount of memory

Answer (score 10):

Numpy 1.10 added the `equal_nan` keyword to `np.allclose` (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html).

So you can do now:

```
In [24]: np.allclose(np.array([1.0, np.NAN, 2.0]), 
                     np.array([1.0, np.NAN, 2.0]), equal_nan=True)
Out[24]: True
```

Comment: This does not work with strings, by the way. Comparing arrays with strings will throw: `TypeError("ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''")`

Answer (score 8):

*Disclaimer: I don't recommend this for regular use, and I wouldn't use it myself, but I could imagine rare circumstances under which it might be useful.*

If the arrays have the same shape and dtype, you could consider using the low-level `memoryview`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> 
>>> a0 = np.array([1.0, np.NAN, 2.0])
>>> ac = a0 * (1+0j)
>>> b0 = np.array([1.0, np.NAN, 2.0])
>>> b1 = np.array([1.0, np.NAN, 2.0, np.NAN])
>>> c0 = np.array([1.0, 0.0, 2.0])
>>> 
>>> memoryview(a0)
<memory at 0x85ba1bc>
>>> memoryview(a0) == memoryview(a0)
True
>>> memoryview(a0) == memoryview(ac) # equal but different dtype
False
>>> memoryview(a0) == memoryview(b0) # hooray!
True
>>> memoryview(a0) == memoryview(b1)
False
>>> memoryview(a0) == memoryview(c0)
False
```

But beware of subtle problems like this:

```
>>> zp = np.array([0.0])
>>> zm = -1*zp
>>> zp
array([ 0.])
>>> zm
array([-0.])
>>> zp == zm
array([ True], dtype=bool)
>>> memoryview(zp) == memoryview(zm)
False
```

which happens because the binary representations differ even though they compare equal (they have to, of course: that's how it knows to print the negative sign)

```
>>> memoryview(zp)[0]
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'
>>> memoryview(zm)[0]
'\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x80'
```

On the bright side, it short-circuits the way you might hope it would:

```
In [47]: a0 = np.arange(10**7)*1.0
In [48]: a0[-1] = np.NAN    
In [49]: b0 = np.arange(10**7)*1.0    
In [50]: b0[-1] = np.NAN     
In [51]: timeit memoryview(a0) == memoryview(b0)
10 loops, best of 3: 31.7 ms per loop
In [52]: c0 = np.arange(10**7)*1.0    
In [53]: c0[0] = np.NAN   
In [54]: d0 = np.arange(10**7)*1.0    
In [55]: d0[0] = 0.0    
In [56]: timeit memoryview(c0) == memoryview(d0)
100000 loops, best of 3: 2.51 us per loop
```

and for comparison:

```
In [57]: timeit np.all((a0 == b0) | (np.isnan(a0) & np.isnan(b0)))
1 loops, best of 3: 296 ms per loop
In [58]: timeit np.all((c0 == d0) | (np.isnan(c0) & np.isnan(d0)))
1 loops, best of 3: 284 ms per loop
```

Comment: (+1) This is great, thanks for taking the time to write it up.

Comment: @aix: I've actually needed something similar in the past (equal-considering-nans-equal), though performance and memory weren't issues so I did it manually.  Might be worth making a feature request.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is any better, but a thought...

```
import numpy
class FloatOrNaN(numpy.float_):
    def __eq__(self, other):
        return (numpy.isnan(self) and numpy.isnan(other)) or super(FloatOrNaN,self).__eq__(other)

a = [1., np.nan, 2.]
one = numpy.array([FloatOrNaN(val) for val in a], dtype=object)
two = numpy.array([FloatOrNaN(val) for val in a], dtype=object)
print one == two   # yields  array([ True,  True,  True], dtype=bool)
```

This pushes the ugliness into the dtype, at the expense of making the inner workings python instead of c (Cython/etc would fix this).  It does, however, greatly reduce memory costs.

Still kinda ugly though :(