# Comparing two pandas dataframes for differences

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I've got a script updating 5-10 columns worth of data , but sometimes the start csv will be identical to the end csv so instead of writing an identical csvfile I want it to do nothing...

How can I compare two dataframes to check if they're the same or not?

```
csvdata = pandas.read_csv('csvfile.csv')
csvdata_old = csvdata

# ... do stuff with csvdata dataframe

if csvdata_old != csvdata:
    csvdata.to_csv('csvfile.csv', index=False)
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Not an expert at Pandas but shouldn't a normal equality comparison work?

Comment: I've had a look at equality but I'm unsure how to use that function, I'm also unable to find anything in search :(

Answer (score 89, accepted):

You also need to be careful to create a copy of the DataFrame, otherwise the csvdata_old will be updated with csvdata (since it points to the same object):

```
csvdata_old = csvdata.copy()
```

To check whether they are equal, you can [use assert_frame_equal as in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322506/pandas-dataframes-with-nans-equality-comparison):

```
from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal
assert_frame_equal(csvdata, csvdata_old)
```

You can wrap this in a function with something like:

```
try:
    assert_frame_equal(csvdata, csvdata_old)
    return True
except:  # appeantly AssertionError doesn't catch all
    return False
```

*There was discussion of a better way...*

Comment: For some reason I get the exception: `Exception: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects`

Comment: That gives you the answer then, right? It's saying that the labels (row and column names/values) aren't identical so then the DataFrames can't be identical. Add another `except` line to Andy's wrapper: `except Exception: return False`

Comment: @Hyflex yep, as Tom points out, just remove the AssertionError (before it was only stopping on AssertionError and raising on anything else)...

Comment: Okay, I fixed the lables (didn't realise I had to reorder the label order of csvdat_old and I've tried incorporating this into my actual data but it updates even though the data is identical when it's output, is there a way to find/see what exactly is "different"?

Comment: How to get the different values in those frames?

Comment: @AndyHayden, is there any way to tell `assert_frame_equal` that ignore the order in which the columns are? I care about the order of the columns but not of the rows. I have ended up defining a variable `cols = ['col_1', ..., 'col_N']` and then `assert_frame_equal(expected[cols], actual[cols])`, but I do not like it too much.

Comment: pandas.util.testing doesn't work anymore, you now should use pandas.testing

Answer (score 49):

Not sure if this is helpful or not, but I whipped together this quick python method for returning just the differences between two dataframes that both have the same columns and shape.

```
def get_different_rows(source_df, new_df):
    """Returns just the rows from the new dataframe that differ from the source dataframe"""
    merged_df = source_df.merge(new_df, indicator=True, how='outer')
    changed_rows_df = merged_df[merged_df['_merge'] == 'right_only']
    return changed_rows_df.drop('_merge', axis=1)
```

Comment: This is the answer I was actually looking for.  Thanks so much

Comment: This is awesome! but may I ask how can it not ignore the data types? Like for example if there's a value `4` on the `source_df` and `4.0` on the `new_df` it should still return a `dataframe` since it would mean there's a difference, Thanks!

Comment: Thank you for this. And the utility function is really useful !

Answer (score 24):

Not sure if this existed at the time the question was posted, but pandas now has a built-in function to test equality between two dataframes: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.equals.html.

Comment: Nope that never existed, it works just as good. (Better because it's a single line vs 5 lines

Comment: How does it work on floats? I hope there is a precision parameter.

Comment: There has to be something better than that. Just a false is not a satisfactory answer

Comment: Not sure whether this is what most people would want.. `DataFrame.equals` does a very deep comparison. For example.. I had 2 dataframes whose values are equal.. but it turns out that `DataFrames` also have some parameters called `Axis 1`, `IntBlock` and `ObjectBlock`. These are defined under `pd._data`. If these are not the same between the 2 objects.. it will result in False

Comment: @Nickpick `DataFrame.eq` probably serves well for locating the unequal elements?

Comment: `df.eq(df2).all().all()` helped overcome the `df.equals` issue to just compare contents

Answer (score 17):

Check using: **df_1.equals(df_2)**   *# Returns True or False*, *details herebelow*

```
In [45]: import numpy as np

In [46]: import pandas as pd

In [47]: np.random.seed(5)

In [48]: df_1= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3))

In [49]: df_1
Out[49]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.441227 -0.330870  2.430771
1 -0.252092  0.109610  1.582481
2 -0.909232 -0.591637  0.187603

In [50]: np.random.seed(5)

In [51]: df_2= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3))

In [52]: df_2
Out[52]: 
          0         1         2
0  0.441227 -0.330870  2.430771
1 -0.252092  0.109610  1.582481
2 -0.909232 -0.591637  0.187603

In [53]: df_1.equals(df_2)
Out[53]: True


In [54]: df_3= pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(3,3))

In [55]: df_3
Out[55]: 
          0         1         2
0 -0.329870 -1.192765 -0.204877
1 -0.358829  0.603472 -1.664789
2 -0.700179  1.151391  1.857331

In [56]: df_1.equals(df_3)
Out[56]: False
```

Comment: There is one catch: `index.names` are not compared. See my answer for details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420842/304209

Answer (score 11):

A more accurate comparison should check for index names separately, because `DataFrame.equals` does not test for that. All the other properties (index values (single/multiindex), values, columns, dtypes) are checked by it correctly.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']], columns=['num', 'name'])
df1 = df1.set_index('name')
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 'a'], [2, 'b'], [3, 'c']], columns=['num', 'another_name'])
df2 = df2.set_index('another_name')

df1.equals(df2)
True

df1.index.names == df2.index.names
False
```

Note: using `index.names` instead of `index.name` makes it work for multi-indexed dataframes as well.

Answer (score 8):

In my case, I had a weird error, whereby even though the indices, column-names
and values were same, the `DataFrames` didnt match. I tracked it down to the
data-types, and it seems `pandas` can sometimes use different datatypes,
resulting in such problems

For example:

`param2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1]})
param1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1], 'b': [2], 'c': [2], 'step': ['alpha']})`

if you check `param1.dtypes` and `param2.dtypes`, you will find that 'a' is of
type `object` for `param1` and is of type `int64` for `param2`. Now, if you do
some manipulation using a combination of `param1` and `param2`, other
parameters of the dataframe will deviate from the default ones.

So after the final dataframe is generated, even though the actual values that
are printed out are same, `final_df1.equals(final_df2)`, may turn out to be
not-equal, because those samll parameters like `Axis 1`, `ObjectBlock`,
`IntBlock` maynot be the same.

A easy way to get around this and compare the values is to use

`final_df1==final_df2`.

However, this will do a element by element comparison, so it wont work if you
are using it to assert a statement for example in `pytest`.

### TL;DR

What works well is

`all(final_df1 == final_df2)`.

This does a element by element comparison, while neglecting the parameters not
important for comparison.

### TL;DR2

If your values and indices are same, but `final_df1.equals(final_df2)` is showing `False`, you can use `final_df1._data` and `final_df2._data` to check the rest of the elements of the dataframes.

Comment: Does anyone know why a data frame read in from a CSV would show as different from a data frame read in from an Excel workbook, even when they are identical?

Answer (score 8):

To pull out the symmetric differences:

```
df_diff = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'num': [1, 4, 3],
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'c'],
})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'num': [1, 2, 3],
    'name': ['a', 'b', 'd'],
})
```

Will yield:

[image]

Note: until the next release of pandas, to avoid the warning about how the sort argument will be set in the future, just add the `sort=False` argument. As below:

```
df_diff = pd.concat([df1,df2], sort=False).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Answer (score 7):

This compares the **values** of two dataframes note the number of row/columns needs to be the same between tables

```
comparison_array = table.values == expected_table.values
print (comparison_array)

>>>[[True, True, True]
    [True, False, True]]

if False in comparison_array:
    print ("Not the same")

#Return the position of the False values
np.where(comparison_array==False)

>>>(array([1]), array([1]))
```

You could then use this index information to return the value that does not match between tables. Since it's zero indexed, it's referring to the 2nd array in the 2nd position which is correct.

Comment: The main benefit here is you can you the index position that is returned by np.where to determine the exact position the table does not match and alert the user to that location.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this below code snippet helps you!

```
import pandas as pd
import datacompy

df_old_original = pd.DataFrame([[1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [7, 7, 7, 7], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [7, 7, 7, 7], [5, 5, 5, 5], [6, 6, 6, 6]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], dtype=object)
df_new_original = pd.DataFrame([[None, None, None, None], [1, 1, 1, 1], [2, 2, 2, 2], [8, 8, 8, 8], [3, 3, 3, 3], [4, 4, 4, 4], [7, 7, 7, 7], [5, 5, 5, 5], [None, None, None, None]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], index=[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], dtype=object)

compare = datacompy.Compare(df_old_original, df_new_original, join_columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'], abs_tol=0, rel_tol=0, df1_name='Old', df2_name='New')
changes_in_old_df = compare.df1_unq_rows
changes_in_new_df = compare.df2_unq_rows
print(changes_in_old_df)
print(changes_in_new_df)
print(Compare.report())
```

Answer (score 1):

### A summary and analysis of some of the answers provided to date

Some of the answers provided fail to detect differences in datasets because they don't consider index values. Let's build two simple datasets and analyze some of the proposed approaches:

```
import pandas as pd

df_1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1], 'b': [2,1]})
df_1
```

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 2 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |

```
df_2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,1], 'b': [1,2]})
df_2
```

|  | a | b |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 |

These two dataframes are different because the first row in the `df_1` is clearly not the same as the first row in the `df_2`. If we apply the [method proposed by Tom Chapin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47085845/11764049), it will not detect the difference because it only compares the combination of values for each column in each row, regardless of the row position (index). So in this example, since the combination (1,2) for columns a and b is already present in `df_1`, it's considered a duplicate when merging with `df_2`, even if it shows up at index 1 instead of 0. For the same reason the [method proposed by leersej](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57812732/11764049) fails as well (you can try to apply these methods and see the results by yourself). The `.equals` [method proposed by Surya](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42242210/11764049) is able to detect the difference, returning `False` in the comparison, but as [pointed out by Dennis Golomazov](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420842/11764049), if you're interested in also checking the equality of indexes, you should add another check, as showed in his answer. In the end if you want to ensure that dataframes have the same column values at the same indexes, I think that the best method is to perform a direct match, as [suggested by alpha_989](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51182925/11764049), however the usage of the [`all()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) method to check the final equality between the two fails, because it iterates over column names and not the boolean outcomes resulting from the comparison. `all(df_1 == df_2)` in fact, returns wrongly `True`. At the end of the day, to safely check if two dataframes are equal (using only the `pandas` library), you should:

```
# 1 compare the two datasets
>>> comparison = (df_1 == df_2)
# 2 - see what columns are matching and what aren't
>>> comparison.all()
a     True
b    False
dtype: bool

# 3 - compare if all columns are matching
>>> comparison.all().all() # equivalent all(comparison.all())
False
# BONUS - row indexes that aren't matching (more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52173171/11764049)
>>> comparison.T.all()[~comparison.T.all()].index
Int64Index([0, 1], dtype='int64')
```

### TL;DR

In order to check the equality of two dataframes, considering also row indexes you can use the `.equals` method as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43420842/11764049), or:

```
comparison = (df_1 == df_2)
equality = comparison.all().all()
not_matching_row_idxs = comparison.T.all()[~comparison.T.all()].index
```

This approach also allows you to find the row indexes that are not matching.

*Note:*
This method only works with dataframes having same index values.