# Comparing two dataframes and getting the differences

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.  Example:

```
df1:
Date       Fruit  Num  Color 
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green

df2:
Date       Fruit  Num  Color 
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green
2013-11-25 Apple  22.1 Red
2013-11-25 Orange  8.6 Orange
```

Each dataframe has the Date as an index. Both dataframes have the same structure.

What i want to do, is compare these two dataframes and find which rows are in df2 that aren't in df1. I want to compare the date (index) and the first column (Banana, APple, etc) to see if they exist in df2 vs df1.

I have tried the following:

- [Compare two DataFrames and output their differences side-by-side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17095101/outputting-difference-in-two-pandas-dataframes-side-by-side-highlighting-the-d)
- [Comparing two pandas dataframes for differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917545/comparing-two-pandas-dataframes-for-differences)

For the first approach I get this error: ***"Exception: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects"***.  I have tried removing the Date as index but get the same error.

On the [third approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917545/comparing-two-pandas-dataframes-for-differences), I get the assert to return False but cannot figure out how to actually see the different rows.

Any pointers would be welcome

Comment: If you do this: http://www.cookbook-r.com/Manipulating_data/Renaming_columns_in_a_data_frame/, will it get rid of the 'identically-labeled DataFrame objects' exception?

Comment: I've changed column names many times to try to get around the issue with no luck.

Comment: FWIW, I changed column names to be "a,b,c,d" on both dataframes and receive the same error message.

Answer (score 138, accepted):

This approach, `df1 != df2`, works only for  dataframes  with identical rows and columns. In fact, all dataframes axes are compared with `_indexed_same` method, and exception is raised if differences found, even in columns/indices order.

If I got you right, you want not to find changes, but symmetric difference. For that, one approach might be concatenate dataframes:

```
>>> df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
>>> df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

group by

```
>>> df_gpby = df.groupby(list(df.columns))
```

get index of unique records

```
>>> idx = [x[0] for x in df_gpby.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]
```

filter

```
>>> df.reindex(idx)
         Date   Fruit   Num   Color
9  2013-11-25  Orange   8.6  Orange
8  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1     Red
```

Comment: This was the answer. I removed the "Date" index and followed this approach and I get right output.

Comment: Is there an easy way to add a flag to this to see which rows were removed/added/changed from df1 to df2?

Comment: @alko I was wondering, does this `pd.concat` add in only the missing items from the `df1`? Or does it replace `df1` completely with `df2`?

Comment: @jakewong `pd.concat` - as used here - does an outer join. In other words, it joins all indices from both df's and this is in fact the default behaviour for `pd.concat()`, here's the docs http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/merging.html

Comment: what is the maximum number of records we can compare using pandas ?

Comment: Using this approach, how do we find out which row is missing from which dataframe. Is there a way to get that info ?

Comment: For people looking at this answer, just go to: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html

Comment: Can you not simply concat the two data-frames e.g. 

df = pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index = True)

And then do df.drop_duplicates(['Date', 'Fruit']) ?  That would give you the the rows that are not in common between df1 and df2, assuming that Date and Fruit are the correct keys for your comparison.

Comment: df.drop_duplicates(['Date', 'Fruit'], keep = False)

Answer (score 97):

Updating and placing, somewhere it will be easier for others to find, *ling*'s comment upon *jur*'s response above.

```py
df_diff = pd.concat([df1,df2]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

---

Testing with these DataFrames:

```py
# with import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24'],
    'Fruit':['Banana','Orange','Apple','Celery'],
    'Num':[22.1,8.6,7.6,10.2],
    'Color':['Yellow','Orange','Green','Green'],
    })

df2 = pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-25','2013-11-25'],
    'Fruit':['Banana','Orange','Apple','Celery','Apple','Orange'],
    'Num':[22.1,8.6,7.6,10.2,22.1,8.6],
    'Color':['Yellow','Orange','Green','Green','Red','Orange'],
    })
```

---

Results in this:

```py
# for df1

         Date   Fruit   Num   Color
0  2013-11-24  Banana  22.1  Yellow
1  2013-11-24  Orange   8.6  Orange
2  2013-11-24   Apple   7.6   Green
3  2013-11-24  Celery  10.2   Green


# for df2

         Date   Fruit   Num   Color
0  2013-11-24  Banana  22.1  Yellow
1  2013-11-24  Orange   8.6  Orange
2  2013-11-24   Apple   7.6   Green
3  2013-11-24  Celery  10.2   Green
4  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1     Red
5  2013-11-25  Orange   8.6  Orange


# for df_diff

         Date   Fruit   Num   Color
4  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1     Red
5  2013-11-25  Orange   8.6  Orange
```

Comment: This is the best answer so far! Very straight forward.

Comment: But this answer would not show the rows if the duplicates are in the same DataFrame. For example, if `df1` contains two identical rows but `df2` doesn't contain any of these.

Comment: @BohdanPylypenko - True! But I am taking it as given that folks get their data within each set unique before they ever get to a step of comparing across separate datasets. (If they don't they are setting themselves up for a confusing jumble of issues in source and across sources to sort out all at once.)

Answer (score 29):

```
# THIS WORK FOR ME

# Get all diferent values
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, how='outer', indicator='Exist')
df3 = df3.loc[df3['Exist'] != 'both']


# If you like to filter by a common ID
df3  = pd.merge(df1, df2, on="Fruit", how='outer', indicator='Exist')
df3  = df3.loc[df3['Exist'] != 'both']
```

Comment: this is the best answer

Comment: This works really well for multi-column dataframes.

Answer (score 26):

Passing the dataframes to concat in a dictionary, results in a multi-index dataframe from which you can easily delete the duplicates, which results in a multi-index dataframe with the differences between the dataframes:

```
import sys
if sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    from StringIO import StringIO
else:
    from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

DF1 = StringIO("""Date       Fruit  Num  Color 
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green
""")
DF2 = StringIO("""Date       Fruit  Num  Color 
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green
2013-11-25 Apple  22.1 Red
2013-11-25 Orange  8.6 Orange""")


df1 = pd.read_table(DF1, sep='\s+')
df2 = pd.read_table(DF2, sep='\s+')
#%%
dfs_dictionary = {'DF1':df1,'DF2':df2}
df=pd.concat(dfs_dictionary)
df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Result:

```
             Date   Fruit   Num   Color
DF2 4  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1     Red
    5  2013-11-25  Orange   8.6  Orange
```

Comment: This is a much easier method, just one more revision may make it more easier. No need to concat in a dictionary, use df = pd.concat([df1,df2]) would do the same

Comment: you should not overwrite built-in keyword `dict`!

Comment: Is there a way to add to this to determine which data frame contained the unique row?

Comment: You can tell by the first level in the multiindex which contains the key of the dataframe in the dictionary (I updated the output with the correct keys)

Answer (score 20):

Since [`pandas >= 1.1.0`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/whatsnew/v1.1.0.html#comparing-two-dataframe-or-two-series-and-summarizing-the-differences) we have [`DataFrame.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.compare.html) and [`Series.compare`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.compare.html#pandas.Series.compare).

> Note: the method can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame objects,
> this means DataFrames with identical row and column labels.

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3],
                    'B': [4, 5, 6],
                    'C': [7, np.NaN, 9]})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 99, 3],
                    'B': [4, 5, 81],
                    'C': [7, 8, 9]})

   A  B    C
0  1  4  7.0
1  2  5  NaN
2  3  6  9.0 

    A   B  C
0   1   4  7
1  99   5  8
2   3  81  9
```

```
df1.compare(df2)

     A          B          C      
  self other self other self other
1  2.0  99.0  NaN   NaN  NaN   8.0
2  NaN   NaN  6.0  81.0  NaN   NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for this information. I haven't moved to 1.1 yet, but this is good to know.

Comment: compare only works if the 2 dataFrames are at the same size. right?

Comment: Yes, see the note in my answer @Rebin

Answer (score 6):

Building on alko's answer that almost worked for me, except for the filtering step (where I get: `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`), here is the final solution I used:

```py
# join the dataframes
united_data = pd.concat([data1, data2, data3, ...])
# group the data by the whole row to find duplicates
united_data_grouped = united_data.groupby(list(united_data.columns))
# detect the row indices of unique rows
uniq_data_idx = [x[0] for x in united_data_grouped.indices.values() if len(x) == 1]
# extract those unique values
uniq_data = united_data.iloc[uniq_data_idx]
```

Comment: Nice addition to the answer. Thanks

Comment: I'm getting the error,' `IndexError: index out of bounds'`, when I try to run the third line.

Answer (score 6):

Get the existing data from `df2` into `df1`:

```
dfe = df2[df2["Fruit"].isin(df1["Fruit"])]
```

Get the non-existing data from `df2` into `df1`:

```
dfn = df2[~ df2["Fruit"].isin(df1["Fruit"])]
```

You can use more than one comparison.

Comment: Works great! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Founder a simple solution here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47132808/9656339

`pd.concat([df1, df2]).loc[df1.index.symmetric_difference(df2.index)]`

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow Tom2shoes. Please don't provide link-only answers, try to extract the content from the link and leave it only as a reference (as the content in the link can be deleted or the link itself can break). For more information refer to ["How do I write a good answer?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). If you believe this question was already answered in another question, please mark it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simpler solution that is faster and better, 
and if the numbers are different can even give you quantities differences:

```
df1_i = df1.set_index(['Date','Fruit','Color'])
df2_i = df2.set_index(['Date','Fruit','Color'])
df_diff = df1_i.join(df2_i,how='outer',rsuffix='_').fillna(0)
df_diff = (df_diff['Num'] - df_diff['Num_'])
```

Here df_diff is a synopsis of the differences. You can even use it to find the differences in quantities. In your example:

[image]

Explanation:
Similarly to comparing two lists, to do it efficiently we should first order them then compare them (converting the list to sets/hashing would also be fast; both are an incredible improvement to the simple O(N^2) double comparison loop

Note: the following code produces the tables:

```
df1=pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24'],
    'Fruit':['Banana','Orange','Apple','Celery'],
    'Num':[22.1,8.6,7.6,10.2],
    'Color':['Yellow','Orange','Green','Green'],
})
df2=pd.DataFrame({
    'Date':['2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-25','2013-11-25'],
    'Fruit':['Banana','Orange','Apple','Celery','Apple','Orange'],
    'Num':[22.1,8.6,7.6,10.2,22.1,8.6],
    'Color':['Yellow','Orange','Green','Green','Red','Orange'],
})
```

Answer (score 3):

```
# given
df1=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24'],
    'Fruit':['Banana','Orange','Apple','Celery'],
    'Num':[22.1,8.6,7.6,10.2],
    'Color':['Yellow','Orange','Green','Green']})
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Date':['2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-24','2013-11-25','2013-11-25'],
    'Fruit':['Banana','Orange','Apple','Celery','Apple','Orange'],
    'Num':[22.1,8.6,7.6,1000,22.1,8.6],
    'Color':['Yellow','Orange','Green','Green','Red','Orange']})

# find which rows are in df2 that aren't in df1 by Date and Fruit
df_2notin1 = df2[~(df2['Date'].isin(df1['Date']) & df2['Fruit'].isin(df1['Fruit']) )].dropna().reset_index(drop=True)

# output
print('df_2notin1\n', df_2notin1)
#      Color        Date   Fruit   Num
# 0     Red  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1
# 1  Orange  2013-11-25  Orange   8.6
```

Answer (score 2):

I got this solution. Does this help you ?

```
text = """df1:
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange 8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple 7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green

df2:
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange 8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple 7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green
2013-11-25 Apple 22.1 Red
2013-11-25 Orange 8.6 Orange



argetz45
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange 118.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple 74.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green
2013-11-25     Nuts    45.8 Brown
2013-11-25 Apple 22.1 Red
2013-11-25 Orange 8.6 Orange
2013-11-26   Pear 102.54    Pale"""
```

.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import re

r = re.compile('([a-zA-Z\d]+).*\n'
               '(20\d\d-[01]\d-[0123]\d.+\n?'
               '(.+\n?)*)'
               '(?=[ \n]*\Z'
                  '|'
                  '\n+[a-zA-Z\d]+.*\n'
                  '20\d\d-[01]\d-[0123]\d)')

r2 = re.compile('((20\d\d-[01]\d-[0123]\d) +([^\d.]+)(?<! )[^\n]+)')

d = OrderedDict()
bef = []

for m in r.finditer(text):
    li = []
    for x in r2.findall(m.group(2)):
        if not any(x[1:3]==elbef for elbef in bef):
            bef.append(x[1:3])
            li.append(x[0])
    d[m.group(1)] = li


for name,lu in d.iteritems():
    print '%s\n%s\n' % (name,'\n'.join(lu))
```

result

```
df1
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange 8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple 7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green

df2
2013-11-25 Apple 22.1 Red
2013-11-25 Orange 8.6 Orange

argetz45
2013-11-25     Nuts    45.8 Brown
2013-11-26   Pear 102.54    Pale
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I saw the answer by @alko and that code worked well.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this method, and it worked. I hope it can help too:

```
"""Identify differences between two pandas DataFrames"""
df1.sort_index(inplace=True)
df2.sort_index(inplace=True)
df_all = pd.concat([df1, df12], axis='columns', keys=['First', 'Second'])
df_final = df_all.swaplevel(axis='columns')[df1.columns[1:]]
df_final[df_final['change this to one of the columns'] != df_final['change this to one of the columns']]
```

Answer (score 1):

use merge outer to find the left outer values whose value is null

```
txt1="""Date,Fruit,Num,Color 
2013-11-24,Banana,22.1,Yellow
2013-11-24,Orange,8.6,Orange
2013-11-24,Apple,7.6,Green
2013-11-24,Celery,10.2,Green"""

txt2="""Date,Fruit,Num,Color 
2013-11-24,Banana,22.1,Yellow
2013-11-24,Orange,8.6,Orange
2013-11-24,Apple,7.6,Green
2013-11-24,Celery,10.2,Green
2013-11-25,Apple,22.1,Red
2013-11-25,Orange,8.6,Orange"""

from io import StringIO
f = StringIO(txt1)
df1 = pd.read_table(f,sep =',')
df1.set_index('Date',inplace=True)

f = StringIO(txt2)
df2 = pd.read_table(f,sep =',')
df2.set_index('Date',inplace=True)

df3 =pd.merge(df2, df1, left_index=True, right_index=True,  how='outer', 
     indicator=True
         ,suffixes=("", "_left")
         ).query("_merge=='left_only'")
remove_columns=[item for item in df3.columns if '_left' in item]
remove_columns.append('_merge')
df3=df3.drop(columns=remove_columns)
print(df3)
```

output:

```
         Date   Fruit   Num  Color 
0  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1     Red
1  2013-11-25  Orange   8.6  Orange
```

Answer (score 0):

One important detail to notice is that your data has **duplicate index values**, so to perform any straightforward comparison we need to turn everything as unique with `df.reset_index()` and therefore we can perform selections based on conditions.  Once in your case the index is defined, I assume that you would like to keep de index so there are a one-line solution:

```
[~df2.reset_index().isin(df1.reset_index())].dropna().set_index('Date')
```

Once the objective from a pythonic perspective is to improve readability, we can break a little bit:

```
# keep the index name, if it does not have a name it uses the default name
index_name = df.index.name if df.index.name else 'index' 

# setting the index to become unique
df1 = df1.reset_index()
df2 = df2.reset_index()

# getting the differences to a Dataframe
df_diff = df2[~df2.isin(df1)].dropna().set_index(index_name)
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this would be useful to you. ^o^

```py
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['0207', '0207'], 'col1': [1, 2]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['0207', '0207', '0208', '0208'], 'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
print(f"df1(Before):\n{df1}\ndf2:\n{df2}")
"""
df1(Before):
   date  col1
0  0207     1
1  0207     2

df2:
   date  col1
0  0207     1
1  0207     2
2  0208     3
3  0208     4
"""

old_set = set(df1.index.values)
new_set = set(df2.index.values)
new_data_index = new_set - old_set
new_data_list = []
for idx in new_data_index:
    new_data_list.append(df2.loc[idx])

if len(new_data_list) > 0:
    df1 = df1.append(new_data_list)
print(f"df1(After):\n{df1}")
"""
df1(After):
   date  col1
0  0207     1
1  0207     2
2  0208     3
3  0208     4
"""
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find the difference between DataFrame row counts:

```
df2.value_counts().sub(df1.value_counts(), fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
Date        Fruit   Num     Color
2013-11-24  Apple   7.6     Green     0.0
            Banana  22.1    Yellow    0.0
            Celery  10.2    Green    -1.0
                    1000.0  Green     1.0
            Orange  8.6     Orange    0.0
2013-11-25  Apple   22.1    Red       1.0
            Orange  8.6     Orange    1.0
dtype: float6
```