# Eliminate pandas dataframe rows with partial matches

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I want to compare two pandas dataframes and find out the rows that are only in df1, by comparing the values in column A and B. I feel like I could somehow perform this by using merge but cannot figure out..

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,11, 111], [2,22, 222], [3, 33, 333]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 11]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

df1

```
    A   B   C
0   1   11  111
1   2   22  222
2   3   33  333
```

df2

```
    A   B
0   1   11
```

Dataframe I want to see

```
    A   B   C
1   2   22  222
2   3   33  333
```

Comment: In the example you are showing, it seems that you want to eliminate rows with partial matches. Is that correct?

Comment: yes that is exactly correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225110/comparing-two-dataframes-and-getting-the-differences):

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,11, 111], [2,22, 222], [3, 33, 333]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 11]], columns=['A', 'B'])
```

Concatenate the dataframes:

```
df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
df.reset_index(drop=True)
```

Groupby your desired comparison columns - in your case, `A` and `B`:

```
df_gpby = df.groupby(['A','B'])
```

Get the indexes for the groups with only one value - i.e. unique `A`,`B` pairs:

```
idx = [x[0] for x in df_gpby.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]
```

Subset the concatenated dataframe by the indexes:

```
df.iloc[idx]
```

Results in:

```
    A   B   C
1   2   22  222
2   3   33  333
```

Answer (score 1):

While vmg's solution is neat, it requires you to know which columns you need to group by. A more generic approach is this:

First subtract one data frame from another:

```
In [46]: df3 = df1.subtract(df2)

In [47]: df3
Out[47]: 
    A   B   C
0   0   0 NaN
1 NaN NaN NaN
2 NaN NaN NaN
```

You see that the interesting rows, are those who don't exist in `df2`, so they are all NaN. Using numpy method you can find those rows:

```
In [50]: np.isnan(df3.iloc[0])
Out[50]: 
A    False
B    False
C     True
Name: 0, dtype: bool

In [51]: np.isnan(df3.iloc[1])
Out[51]: 
A    True
B    True
C    True
Name: 1, dtype: bool
```

Now, that you know how to locate those rows, you can do a crazy one liner:

```
In [52]: df1.iloc[[idx for idx, row in df3.iterrows() if 
                  all(np.isnan(df3.iloc[idx]))]]
Out[52]: 
   A   B    C
1  2  22  222
2  3  33  333
```

#### update, let's add a generic function

```
def substract_dataframe(df1, df2):
    for i in [df1, df2]:
        if not isinstance(i, pd.DataFrame):
            raise ValueError(("Wrong argument given! 
                             All arguments must be DataFrame instances"))
    df = df1.subtract(df2)
    return df1.iloc[[idx for idx, row in df.iterrows() if      
                    all(np.isnan(df.iloc[idx]))]]
```

testing ...

```
In [54]: substract_dataframe(df1, df2)
Out[54]: 
   A   B    C
1  2  22  222
2  3  33  333

In [55]: substract_dataframe(df1, 'sdf')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-6ce801e88ce4> in <module>()
----> 1 substract_dataframe(df1, 'sdf')

<ipython-input-53-e5d7db966311> in substract_dataframe(df1, df2)
      2     for i in [df1, df2]:
      3         if not isinstance(i, pd.DataFrame):
----> 4             raise ValueError("Wrong argument given! All arguments must be DataFrame instances")
      5     df = df1.subtract(df2)
      6     return df1.iloc[[idx for idx, row in df.iterrows() if all(np.isnan(df.iloc[idx]))]]

ValueError: Wrong argument given! All arguments must be DataFrame instances
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `merge` with `indicator`, was added in `0.17.0` version

```
In [3544]: df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator='_b').query('_b != "both"').drop('_b', 1)
Out[3544]:
   A   B    C
1  2  22  222
2  3  33  333
```

Details

```
In [3545]: df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator='_b')
Out[3545]:
   A   B    C         _b
0  1  11  111       both
1  2  22  222  left_only
2  3  33  333  left_only

In [3546]: df1.merge(df2, how='left', indicator='_b').query('_b != "both"')
Out[3546]:
   A   B    C         _b
1  2  22  222  left_only
2  3  33  333  left_only
```