# Python How to get values that are in one dataframe but not a second

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

I am working with two dataframes that are very similar, and I'm trying to figure out how to get the data that is in one and not the other - and visa versa.

Here is my code so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


def report_diff(x):
return x[0] if x[0] == x[1] else '{} ---> {}'.format(*x)

old = pd.read_excel('File 1')
new = pd.read_excel('File 2')
old['version'] = 'old'
new['version'] = 'new'

full_set = pd.concat([old,new],ignore_index=True)

changes = full_set.drop_duplicates(subset=['ID','Type', 'Total'], keep='last')

duplicated = changes.duplicated(subset=['ID', 'Type'], keep=False)

dupe_accts = changes[duplicated]

change_new = dupe_accts[(dupe_accts['version'] == 'new')]

change_old = dupe_accts[(dupe_accts['version'] == 'old' )]

change_new = change_new.drop(['version'], axis=1)

change_old = change_old.drop(['version'],axis=1)

change_new.set_index('Employee ID', inplace=True)

change_old.set_index('Employee ID', inplace=True)

diff_panel = pd.Panel(dict(df1=change_old,df2=change_new))
diff_output = diff_panel.apply(report_diff, axis=0)
```

And so the next step would be to get the data that is only in old and only in new.

My first attempt was:

```
 changes['duplicate']=changes['Employee ID'].isin(dupe_accts)
removed_accounts = changes[(changes['duplicate'] == False) & (changes['version'] =='old')]
```

Comment: Fix the quote in `new = pd.read_excel('File 2)`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225110/comparing-two-dataframes-and-getting-the-differences

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got dizzy looking at your code!

IIUC:

Use the parameter `indicator=True` within a `merge`

Consider the dataframes `old` and `new`

```
old = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        ID=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        Type=list('AAABB'),
        Total=[9 for _ in range(5)],
        ArbitraryColumn=['blah' for _ in range(5)]
    ))

new = old.head(2)
```

Then `merge` and `query` the `left_only`

```
old.merge(
    new, 'outer', on=['ID', 'Type'],
    suffixes=['', '_'], indicator=True
).query('_merge == "left_only"')

  ArbitraryColumn  ID  Total Type ArbitraryColumn_  Total_     _merge
2            blah   3      9    A              NaN     NaN  left_only
3            blah   4      9    B              NaN     NaN  left_only
4            blah   5      9    B              NaN     NaN  left_only
```

We can `reindex` to restrict to the original columns

```
old.merge(
    new, 'outer', on=['ID', 'Type'],
    suffixes=['', '_'], indicator=True
).query('_merge == "left_only"').reindex_axis(old.columns, axis=1)

  ArbitraryColumn  ID  Total Type
2            blah   3      9    A
3            blah   4      9    B
4            blah   5      9    B
```

Comment: I could upvote twice but I already did reading the first sentence:)

Comment: @piRSquared Thank you! Very simply solution to what I was looking for.

Comment: @A-Za-z btw folks on Meta lack a sense of humor https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/293438/326787

Comment: that's not a bug; it's a feature :D

Comment: @piRSquared What would be the way to get data that is in the right data frame but no the left? I changed to "righ_only" and I get the two columns I join on, but it's still data only in the left. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454258/how-to-get-data-in-the-right-dataframe-that-isnt-in-the-left-dataframe

Comment: @TroyR there are nuances related to other columns getting a suffix appended to the column names and where I `reindex_axis(old.columns)`  It would be best to ask another question.  Also, that way everyone gets to benefit from the knowledge.

Comment: @piRSquared Here is a new link working towards what I'm currently working on trying to figure out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43454258/how-to-get-data-in-the-right-dataframe-that-isnt-in-the-left-dataframe