# How to get data in the right dataframe that isn't in the left dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames and I am trying to output the data that is in one but not the other.

I can get the data in the first dataframe but not the second using

```
only_new = old.merge(
new, 'outer', on=['Employee ID', 'Benefit Plan Type'],
suffixes=['','_'], indicator=True
).query('_merge == "left_only"').reindex_axis(old.columns, axis=1)
```

Here is what I'm using to get the data that's only in my second dataframe

```
only_new =new.merge(
old, 'outer', on=['Employee ID', 'Benefit Plan Type'],
suffixes=['','_'], indicator=True
).query('_merge == "left only"').reindex_axis(new.columns, axis=1)
```

But it doesn't return any data, but using Excel I can see that there should be a couple of rows.

It seems like this should work

```
only_new = old.merge(new, on='Employee ID', indicator=True, how='outer',
       only_new[only_new['_merge'] == 'right_only'])
```

But I get

```
SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the dataframes `old` and `new`

```
old = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        ID=[1, 2, 3, 4, 5],
        Type=list('AAABB'),
        Total=[9 for _ in range(5)],
        ArbitraryColumn=['blah' for _ in range(5)]
    ))

new = pd.DataFrame(dict(
        ID=[3, 4, 5, 6, 7],
        Type=list('ABBCC'),
        Total=[9 for _ in range(5)],
        ArbitraryColumn=['blah' for _ in range(5)]
    ))
```

Then to take the symmetrically identical solution

```
old.merge(
    new, 'outer', on=['ID', 'Type'],
    suffixes=['_', ''], indicator=True  # changed order of suffixes
).query('_merge == "right_only"').reindex_axis(new.columns, axis=1)
#                   \......../                 \./
#   changed from `left` to `right`      reindex with `new`

  ArbitraryColumn  ID  Total Type
5            blah   6    9.0    C
6            blah   7    9.0    C
```

Answer (score 3):

It seems you need change `'_merge == "left_only"'` to `'_merge == "right_only"'`.

Comment: That works. When I output it I only get the two columns I'm joining on, and the first one I get all columns. Is that coming from somewhere else in the code?

Comment: Hmmm, it seems main problem is in `reindex_axis`. If remove it get same output, because `reindex_axis` filter out data, which are not  in `old.columns` or in `new.columns`

Comment: Looking at the output closer it is returning the data in the first data frame, but only the ID and plan type columns, which is what the top half does correctly. I'm playing around with it to get the other way around.