# Compare 2 DataFrames for semi matching rows

Tags: python, dataframe

I have 2 dataframes with strings in the cells:

```
df1

ID  t1  t2  t3
0   x1  y1  z1
1   x2  y2  z2 
2   x3  y3  z3 
3   x4  y4  z4  
4   x1  y5  z5 

df2

ID  t1  t2  t3
0   x3  y3  z3
1   x4  y4  z4 
2   x1  y1  z1 
3   x2  y2  z2  
4   x1  y7  z5
```

I found that I can compare the differences in rows with:

```
#exactly the same t1, t2, and t3
pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['t1', 't2', 't3'], how='inner')
```

This will find an exact match between the rows (where t1 in df1 equals t1 in df2, etc.).

How can I find a semi match between the 2 dataframes for a specific column? That is, where there could be a difference in only the specified column in addition to the exact matches? For example, if I specify `t2`, a match will be `t1 in df1 = t1 in df2`, `t2 in df1 != df2`, `t3 in df1 = t3 in df3` (for example, row `ID=4` in the 2 dataframes will match this in addition to the exact matches).

**Update 1:**

It seems like a lot of answers take order into consideration (if the rows are not exactly align the method will fail).

Try the following to check your method:

```
d1 = {'Entity1': ['x1', 'x2','x3','x4','x1', 'x6', 'x1'], 'Relationship': ['y1', 'y2','y3','y4','y5','y6', 'y9'], 'Entity2': ['z1', 'z2','z3','z4','z5','z6', 'z5']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=d1)


d2 = {'Entity1': ['x3', 'x4','x1','x2','x6','x1'], 'Relationship': ['y3', 'y4','y1','y2','y6','y7'], 'Entity2': ['z3', 'z4','z1','z2','z7','z5']}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=d2)
```

Note that one of the exact matches is `x2, y2, z2`, and one of the semi-match is `df1 = x1, y5, z5`, `df2 = x1, y7,z5`

Comment: Are the following what you are looking for? `df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['t1', 't2', 't3'], how='outer');df3[df3.isna().any(axis=1)]` The result is a row by row extraction of the mismatched rows.

Comment: Do you just want to merge on `t1` and `t3`? `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['t1', 't3'], how='inner')`

Answer (score 4):

You could merge the two dataframes and then filter for all rows where t1 and t2 are the same on both sides:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
df3[(df3["t1_x"] == df3["t1_y"]) & (df3["t3_x"] == df3["t3_y"])]
```

Comment: That's really good! This seems to give me the number of only 1 mismatched (like `ID=4` row). How can I get both these mismatched and full matches (from the question "...in addition to the exact matches")? Do I need to merge both data frames? That is, merge the result from `pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['t1', 't2', 't3'], how='inner')`? Will I have redundancies?

Comment: Are you looking for matches and semi-matches or are you looking for mismatches?

Comment: Not sure what you define as semi-matches vs mismatches. I'm looking for 1 mismatch in 1 column where the other columns are matches, in addition to full matches. Also, this seems to take order of rows into account (it fails if you switch the rows)

Answer (score 1):

The code I wrote in the comments is a way to get only the discrepancies.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['t1', 't2', 't3'], how='outer')
df3[df3.isna().any(axis=1)]

ID_x    t1  t2  t3  ID_y
4   4.0     x1  y5  z5  NaN
5   NaN     x1  y7  z5  4.0
```

All mismatches and exact matches can be retrieved by outer join if required.

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['t1', 't2', 't3'], how='outer')

    ID_x    t1  t2  t3  ID_y
0   0.0     x1  y1  z1  2.0
1   1.0     x2  y2  z2  3.0
2   2.0     x3  y3  z3  0.0
3   3.0     x4  y4  z4  1.0
4   4.0     x1  y5  z5  NaN
5   NaN     x1  y7  z5  4.0
```

Comment: Thanks! But this assumes that the order of the rows matter (if you switch row 4 and row 5 in `df2` this will fail)

Comment: I changed the order of df2 and the result is the same, how can it fail?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a generic and heavy duty [function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51683883/8350440) that can do what you are trying to achieve and a lot more (e.g. ignore certain columns)

```
>>> dict1 = diff_func(df1, df2, uid=['t1','t3'], labels=('df1','df2'))
DataType check: Passed
Uniqueness check: ['t1', 't3']
df1: 5 out of 5 are unique (100.0%).
df2: 5 out of 5 are unique (100.0%).
```

To get the dataframe where `t1` and `t3` are the same but `t2` is different:

```
>>> dict1['Diff']                 
  df1 or df2  t1  t2  t3
0        df1  x1  y5  z5
1        df2  x1  y7  z5
```

The column named `df1 or df2` tells you where the row came from and you can visually inspect each row by scanning top and bottom--rather than left and right--to identify the difference. (Imagine having 50 columns, a side-by-side view would not be as readable.)

To get the dataframe where all the columns have the same value (ignoring the index):

```
>>> dict1['Merge']
   t1  t2  t3
0  x1  y1  z1
1  x2  y2  z2
2  x3  y3  z3
3  x4  y4  z4
```

The advantage over one of the answers is that it doesn't matter if a specific row of data have different indexes. Note that your `x4, y4, z4` sit in `ID=3` and `ID=1` respectively.

Do refer to my article [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-compare-2-dataframes-easily-b8f6788d5f07?sk=9d17af740e2c4ef4e776b0f5371840b4) for a more detailed explanation.

**Update 1**

I've modified the [code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51683883/8350440) to cater to situations where there are multiple rows where the columns to be compared on have the same value.

```
>>> dict1['Diff']
  df1 or df2  Entity1  Relationship  Entity2
0        df1       x1            y5       z5
1        df1       x1            y9       z5
2        df2       x1            y7       z5
```

Based on your new example, there are records which do not have similar values in both tables for the columns to be compared on:

```
>>> dict1['Left_only']
  Entity1 Relationship Entity2
1      x6           y6      z6
>>> dict1['Right_only']
  Entity1 Relationship Entity2
3      x6           y6      z7
```

Since `Entity2` differs for these 2 records in the `df1` and `df2` (also known as `left` and `right` dataframe respectively, they are not in the `Diff` dataframe.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to almost work. If there are 2 rows in `df1` that are also a match (`x1`, `y9`, `z5`) this stops working though

Comment: this should work now, I've updated the code in the initial page to cater to the situation that you mentioned.

Comment: @Penguin: Did you managed to check with my updated code?

Answer (score 1):

Or even better with `eq`:

```
>>> df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_index=True, right_index=True)
>>> df3.loc[df1.eq(df2)[['t1', 't3']].all(1)]
   ID_x t1_x t2_x t3_x  ID_y t1_y t2_y t3_y
4     4   x1   y5   z5     4   x1   y7   z5
>>>
```

This merges the dataframes and keeps the rows where `df1` is the same as `df2` on both of the columns `t1` and `t3`.

### Edit for the update:

If you also want to match rows in different indexes, try `isin`:

```
print(df3[np.isin(df1, df2).any(1) & (~np.isin(df1, df2).all(1))].dropna())
```

Output:

```
  Entity1_x Relationship_x Entity2_x Entity1_y Relationship_y Entity2_y
4        x1             y5        z5        x6             y6        z7
5        x6             y6        z6        x1             y7        z5
```

Comment: Thanks! But this assumes that the order of the rows matter (if you switch row 4 and row 5 in `df2` this will fail)

Comment: @Penguin Yeah, all of the answers are like that, will edit one that works for all rows

Comment: @Penguin Edited my answer with something that works for unordered rows, with `isin`, feel free to check it out.

Comment: @Penguin What's the desired output for that one?

Comment: @Penguin Edited my answer with something that works (if I understand update 1 correctly).

Comment: It didn't quite work. The update you made finds the exact matches but not the semi matches. Thanks though!

Comment: @Penguin before the bounty ends, could you show me the expected output for this example data?

Comment: @Penguin Weight! I think I though of something, `df3[np.isin(df1, df2).all(1) & (~df1.eq(df2).any(1))]`

Comment: Hmm this seems to give the same output as your edit

Comment: @Penguin Check my new answer, this definietely should work

Comment: This doesn't print anything... The dataframe is empty...

Comment: @Penguin Could you please edit your question with a desired output?

Comment: @Penguin I am so sorry, it was my typo, edited my answer