# Joining pandas dataframes of identical columns and getting ONLY the items in table B not present in A

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, join

I have two dataframes, dfA and dfB of identical columns. I'm looking to get only the records from dataframe dfB that are not present in dataframe dfA.

to be clear, I do not want to get the records in dfA that are not in dfB.

I managed to hack something together that works using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225110/comparing-two-dataframes-and-getting-the-differences), but the code is not easy to understand and by extension not very pythonic.

I'm looking for a more elegant solution, perhaps using pandas join/merge/append but wasn't able to make it work.

Example of what I want:

```
  dfA: 
  Date       Category  Price 
1 2013-11-24 Coat      22.1
2 2013-11-24 Shirt     8.7
3 2013-11-01 Socks     9     <<< Only present in this df

  dfB:
  Date       Category  Price 
1 2013-11-24 Coat      22.1
2 2013-11-24 Shirt     8.7
3 2013-11-24 Helmet    2.1   <<< Only present in this df
4 2013-11-24 Pants     10.7  <<< Only present in this df

  Result:
  Date       Category  Price 
1 2013-11-24 Helmet    2.1
2 2013-11-24 Pants     10.7
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One of the idiomatic approaches is to use `merge(..., how='outer', indicator=True)` and to filter resulting DF by generated column `_merge`:

```
In [18]: (A.merge(B, how='outer', indicator=True)
           .query("_merge == 'right_only'")
           .drop('_merge',1))
Out[18]:
         Date Category  Price
3  2013-11-24   Helmet    2.1
4  2013-11-24    Pants   10.7
```

Comment: Precisely what I was looking for. Learned a lot. Thank you.

Comment: @Idodo, glad i could help :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.merge.html) with outer join and filter by indicator column with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = pd.merge(dfA, dfB, indicator=True, how='outer')
print (df)
         Date Category  Price      _merge
0  2013-11-24     Coat   22.1        both
1  2013-11-24    Shirt    8.7        both
2  2013-11-01    Socks    9.0   left_only
3  2013-11-24   Helmet    2.1  right_only
4  2013-11-24    Pants   10.7  right_only

df1 = df[df['_merge'] == 'right_only'].drop('_merge', axis=1)
print (df1)
         Date Category  Price
3  2013-11-24   Helmet    2.1
4  2013-11-24    Pants   10.7
```

Answer (score 1):

In case you have a unique column in your table you are filtering by. Perhaps by `Category` in your case.

You could use :

```
dfB[~dfB['Category'].isin(dfA['Category'])]
```

Comment: Not quite what I was looking for, but great nonetheless.