# Add an empty row if index of the column isn't there in pandas

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, dataframe, row

I have two dataframes `df` and `df1`. so i want to take the difference `df` and `df1` but the number of rows are not same. Like row number 5,6,7 of `df1` are not there in `df`.

## df

```
        wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave  
0    4050.32    3  0.28269  0.07365  22.16080  4050.311360   
1    4208.98    5  0.48122  0.08765  44.90035  4208.972962   
2    4374.94    9  0.71483  0.11429  86.96497  4374.927110   
3    4379.74    9  0.31404  0.09107  30.44271  4379.760601   
4    4398.01   14  0.50415  0.09845  52.83236  4398.007473 
5    5520.50    1  0.06148  0.12556   8.21685  5520.484742   
6    6052.67    1  0.04802  0.24632  12.59131  6052.650064
```

## df1

```
        wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave  
0    4050.32    3  0.28616  0.07521  22.91064  4050.327388   
1    4208.98    6  0.48781  0.08573  44.51609  4208.990029   
2    4374.94    9  0.71548  0.11437  87.10152  4374.944513   
3    4379.74   10  0.31338  0.09098  30.34791  4379.778009   
4    4398.01   15  0.49950  0.08612  45.78707  4398.020367   
5    4502.21    9  0.56362  0.10114  60.67868  4502.223123   
6    4508.28    3  0.69554  0.11600  85.88428  4508.291777   
7    4512.99    2  0.20486  0.08891  19.38745  4512.999332
8    5520.50    1  0.06148  0.12556   8.21685  5520.484742   
9    6052.67    1  0.04802  0.24632  12.59131  6052.650064 

path_to_files = '/home/Desktop/computed_2d_blaze/'
lst = []
for filen in [x for x in os.listdir(path_to_files) if '.ares' in x]:
   df = pd.read_table(path_to_files+filen, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')
   df = df.drop_duplicates('wave')
   df = df.sort_values('wave', ascending=True)
   df = df.reset_index(drop=True)
   df[filen] = None
   lst.append(df)




path_to_files1 = '/home/Desktop/computed_1d/'
lst1 = []
for filen in [x for x in os.listdir(path_to_files1) if '.ares' in x]:
   df1 = pd.read_table(path_to_files1+filen, skiprows=0, usecols=(0,1,2,3,4,8),names=['wave','num','stlines','fwhm','EWs','MeasredWave'],delimiter=r'\s+')
   df1 = df1.sort_values('wave', ascending=True)
   #df1 = df1.drop_duplicates('wave')
   df1 = df1.reset_index(drop=True)
   lst1.append(df1)
```

So what i want to do is like, i want to subtract the dataframes on the basis of cloumn `wave`. So i want to make sure that each index of `df.wave` gets subtracted from the correct index of df1. If the index of `wave`(row) is not there in dataframe then i want to add an empty row to make sure it doesn't messes up the rest of the data.

The desired output of df should look like this:

```
        wave  num  stlines     fwhm       EWs  MeasredWave  
0    4050.32    3  0.28269  0.07365  22.16080  4050.311360   
1    4208.98    5  0.48122  0.08765  44.90035  4208.972962   
2    4374.94    9  0.71483  0.11429  86.96497  4374.927110   
3    4379.74    9  0.31404  0.09107  30.44271  4379.760601   
4    4398.01   14  0.50415  0.09845  52.83236  4398.007473 
5       0.00    0  0.00     0.00      0.00        0.00
6       0.00    0  0.00     0.00      0.00        0.00
7       0.00    0  0.00     0.00      0.00        0.00
8    5520.50    1  0.06148  0.12556   8.21685  5520.484742   
9    6052.67    1  0.04802  0.24632  12.59131  6052.650064
```

Comment: Why not iterate the data in a for loop once for missing rows and add data on the rows you want

Comment: check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225110/comparing-two-dataframes-and-getting-the-differences)

Comment: it wasn't that helpful. @anky_91

Comment: @GyanenderGandhar I think you can merge them on "wave" and then drop raws with NaN. If I don't understand you right, please add desired output for your example.

Comment: yep added the desired result. @AnnaIliukovich-Strakovskaia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given:

## df

```
      wave num  stlines     fwhm      EWs MeasredWave
0  4050.32   3  0.28269  0.07365  22.1608      4050.31
1  4208.98   5  0.48122  0.08765  44.9004      4208.97
2  4374.94   9  0.71483  0.11429   86.965      4374.93
3  4379.74   9  0.31404  0.09107  30.4427      4379.76
4  4398.01  14  0.50415  0.09845  52.8324      4398.01
5   5520.5   1  0.06148  0.12556  8.21685      5520.48
6  6052.67   1  0.04802  0.24632  12.5913      6052.65
```

## df1:

```
      wave num  stlines     fwhm      EWs MeasredWave
0  4050.32   3  0.28269  0.07365  22.1608      4050.31
1  4208.98   5  0.48122  0.08765  44.9004      4208.97
2  4374.94   9  0.71483  0.11429   86.965      4374.93
3  4379.74   9  0.31404  0.09107  30.4427      4379.76
4  4398.01  14  0.50415  0.09845  52.8324      4398.01
5  4502.21   9  0.56362  0.10114  60.6787      4502.22
6  4508.28   3  0.69554    0.116  85.8843      4508.29
7  4512.99   2  0.20486  0.08891  19.3875         4513
8   5520.5   1  0.06148  0.12556  8.21685      5520.48
9  6052.67   1  0.04802  0.24632  12.5913      6052.65
```

Try this:

```
df_new = pd.merge(df1, df, on = 'wave', how = 'left')[['wave', 'num_y', 'stlines_y', 'fwhm_y', 'EWs_y', 'MeasredWave_y']]
df_new.fillna(0, inplace = True)
df_new['wave'] = df_new['wave']*df1['wave'].isin(df['wave']).astype(int)
```

Output:

## df_new

```
      wave  num_y  stlines_y   fwhm_y     EWs_y  MeasredWave_y
0  4050.32      3    0.28269  0.07365  22.16080     4050.311360
1  4208.98      5    0.48122  0.08765  44.90035     4208.972962
2  4374.94      9    0.71483  0.11429  86.96497     4374.927110
3  4379.74      9    0.31404  0.09107  30.44271     4379.760601
4  4398.01     14    0.50415  0.09845  52.83236     4398.007473
5     0.00      0    0.00000  0.00000   0.00000        0.000000
6     0.00      0    0.00000  0.00000   0.00000        0.000000
7     0.00      0    0.00000  0.00000   0.00000        0.000000
8  5520.50      1    0.06148  0.12556   8.21685     5520.484742
9  6052.67      1    0.04802  0.24632  12.59131     6052.650064
```