# Pandas: Tracking changes in d1. Compare d1 & d2 dataframes, d1 changes write in d3 dataframe and then d3 add to d2 dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have three dataframes.

d1 - new data

```
 A;B;C A
 BC KG;8530;8604269 
 ABC KG;8530;8604290 
 ABC KG;8530;8604291
```

d2 is history data.

```
A;B;C 
ABC KG;8530;8604269 
ABC KG;8530;8604290 
Firm KG;8530;8604267 
Firm KG;8530;8604268
```

d3 changes

```
ABC KG;8530;8604291
```

If I have some rows in d1 which do not exist in d2 then changes in d3 will be the rows only from d1.

After compare I want to write d3 changes in file and then add d3 changes in d2 History.

After first run I will have in

d3 changes

```
ABC KG;8530;8604291
```

then d3 add to d2

After second run I will have in d3 changes `NULL`

Because `ABC KG;8530;8604291` exists in d2

how to solve this problem?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? If so can you post [your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: not 100% following your logic, you want to - replace data in d1 if it exists in d2 with data from d3?

Comment: please find the given link it matches your issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647534/python-pandas-find-difference-between-two-data-frames

Comment: Hi, i tried this:https://www.pybloggers.com/2019/01/quick-tip-comparing-two-pandas-dataframes-and-getting-the-differences/  and also this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225110/comparing-two-dataframes-and-getting-the-differences/59050461#59050461

Comment: I want to scrape data and store into d1. d2 is my history dataframe. I want to check, does the data (rows) from d1 exist in d2 (history data) if No do nothing. If some or all rows from d1 not exist in d2 then this rows are new data(changed data) and this data i would like to write to d3 for next steps, and also new data (raws) add to d2 in history dataframe.