# Best way to compare two huge dataframes in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a use case where I need to compare a file from s3 bucket with the output of a sql query.

Below is how I am reading the s3 file.

```
if s3_data is None:                                                                                 
   s3_data = pd.read_feather(BytesIO(obj.get()['Body'].read()))                                    
else:                                                                                               
   s3_data = s3_data.append(pd.read_feather(BytesIO(obj.get()['Body'].read())), ignore_index=True)
```

Below is how I am reading from the database.

```
db_data=pandas.read_sql
```

Now I need to compare s3_data with db_data. Both of these dataframes are huge with as much as 2 million rows of data each.

The format of the data is somewhat like below.

```
name | Age | Gender
--------------------
Peter| 30  | Male
Tom  | 24  | Male
Riya | 28  | Female
```

Now I need to validate whether exact same rows with same column data exist in both s3 file and db.
I tried using `dataframe.compare()` but the kind of results it gives is not what I am looking for. The position of the row in the dataframe is not relevant for me. So if 'Tom' appears in row 1 or 3 in one of the dataframes while on a different position in other, it should still pass the equality validation as long as the record itself with same column values is present in both. `dataframe.compare()` is not helping me in this case.

The alternate approach which I took is to use `csv_diff`. I merged all the columns into one in the following way and saved it as a csv in my local creating two csv files- one for s3 data and one for db data.

```
data
------------
Peter+30+Male
Tom+24+Male
Riya+28+Female
```

Then, using below code, I am comparing the files.

```
s3_file = load_csv(open("s3.csv"),key="data")
db_file = load_csv(open("db.csv"),key="data")
diff = compare(s3_file,db_file)
```

This works but is not very performant as I have to first write huge csv files with size as big as 500mb to local and then read and compare them this way.

Is there a better way to handle the comparison part without the need to write files to local and also at the same time ensuring that I am able to compare entire records(with each column value compared for a given row) for equality irrespective of the position of the row in the dataframe?

Comment: Is the plan to do it on your local machine?

Comment: Yes. Not on my local but on an on-premises windows box.

Comment: If not pyspark and clusters might be the solution. You can try joining dfs on one/two column and then find the discrepancies

Comment: This [solution ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225110/comparing-two-dataframes-and-getting-the-differences)solves the problem very neatly.