# python pandas - compare two dataframes in multiple ways by custom ID

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, compare

I need to check what has changed over time in two datasets with different date:

Prior date:

```
Date      ID        Value      Category  Subcategory
30-Nov    0001      100.00     A         A100
30-Nov    0002      200.00     B         B120
30-Nov    0003      300.00     C         C300
30-Nov    0004      450.00     D         D900
30-Nov    0005      500.00     D         D900
```

Current date:

```
Date      ID        Value      Category  Subcategory
31-Dec    0001      100.00     A         A100
31-Dec    0002      200.00     B         B101
31-Dec    0003      300.00     C         C300
31-Dec    0004      400.00     E         E900
31-Dec    0006      600.00     D         D900
```

Now I need to create 4 dataframes:

1. Changes in Value:

```
Date      ID        Value      Category  Subcategory Prior Value
31-Dec    0004      400.00     E         E900        450.00
```

2. Changes in Category:

```
Date      ID        Value      Category  Subcategory Prior Category
31-Dec    0004      400.00     E         E900        D
```

3. Changes in Subcategory, but only if category didn't change:

```
Date      ID        Value      Category  Subcategory Prior Subcategory
31-Dec    0002      200.00     B         B101        B120
```

4. Items population change:

```
Date      ID        Value      Category  Subcategory
31-Dec    0006      600.00     D         D900
30-Nov    0005      500.00     D         D900
```

I think I should first run the population check and exclude those breaks, so I will have only two datasets with identical ID sets. I will follow the examples from here:
[Comparing two dataframes and getting the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225110/comparing-two-dataframes-and-getting-the-differences)

For comparing 1to1 values I found a numpy piece of code but it compares it by default index, not by ID, how to do it using my ID column as record identifier? This is going to be a large dataset and I can't base it on default index.

```
value_df = current_df
value_df['prior value'] = np.where(prior_df['Value'] == current_df['Value'], 'Match', prior_df['Value'])
value_df = value_df[value_df['prior value'] != 'Match']
```

For multiple conditions do I have to filter it out step by step (first filter out category change, then filter subcategory change) or can I use AND to concatenate the conditions?

below is the code for creating dataframes:

```
prior_data = {'Date': ['30-Nov','30-Nov','30-Nov','30-Nov', '30-Nov'],
          'ID': ['0001','0002','0003','0004', '0005'],
          'Value' : [100.00, 200.00, 300.00, 450.00, 500.00],
          'Category' : ['A','B','C','D','D'],
          'Subcategory' : ['A100','B120','C300','D900','D900']}


current_data = {'Date': ['31-Dec','31-Dec','31-Dec','31-Dec','31-Dec'],
          'ID': ['0001','0002','0003','0004', '0006'],
          'Value' : [100.00, 200.00, 300.00, 400.00, 600.00],
          'Category' : ['A','B','C','E','D'],
          'Subcategory' : ['A100','B101','C300','E900','D900']}

prior_df = pd.DataFrame(prior_data)
current_df = pd.DataFrame(current_data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure if it is the fastest possible solution, but this problem seems to call for `pd.merge`. As you say, let's first deal with things that are in one dataframe but not the other:

```
def get_only_left(df1, df2):
    left_merge = pd.merge(df1, df2, on='ID', suffixes=('', '_other'), how='left')
    added_columns = [c + '_other' for c in df1.columns if c != 'ID']
    mask = left_merge.loc[:, added_columns].isna().all(axis=1)
    return left_merge[mask].drop(added_columns, axis=1)

pd.concat([get_only_left(prior_df, current_df), get_only_left(current_df, prior_df)])
```

This gives

```
     Date    ID  Value Category Subcategory
4  30-Nov  0005  500.0        D        D900
4  31-Dec  0006  600.0        D        D900
```

Then, let's deal with properly changing values.

```
columns = list(current_df.columns)
df = pd.merge(current_df, prior_df, on='ID', suffixes=('', '_prior'), how='inner')
mask = df['Value'] != df['Value_prior']
df[mask].loc[:, columns + ['Value_prior']]
```

This gives

```
     Date    ID  Value Category Subcategory  Value_prior
3  31-Dec  0004  400.0        E        E900        450.0
```

Then similarly:

```
mask = df['Category'] != df['Category_prior']
df[mask].loc[:, columns + ['Category_prior']]
```

gives

```
     Date    ID  Value Category Subcategory Category_prior
3  31-Dec  0004  400.0        E        E900              D
```

And finally

```
import numpy as np
mask = np.logical_and(df['Category'] == df['Category_prior'], df['Subcategory'] != df['Subcategory_prior'])
df[mask].loc[:, columns + ['Subcategory_prior']]
```

gives

```
     Date    ID  Value Category Subcategory Subcategory_prior
1  31-Dec  0002  200.0        B        B101              B120
```