# Comparing two data frames with different columns and getting the differences

Tags: python, pandas

I have a similar question as here [Comparing two data frames and getting the differences](https://%20https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225110/comparing-two-dataframes-and-getting-the-differences)
But columns in df1 is a subset of columns in df2.

```
df1:
Date       Fruit  Num  Color 
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green

df2:
Date       Fruit  Num  Color  A
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow 1 
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange 2
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green  3 
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green  4
2013-11-25 Apple  22.1 Red    5
2013-11-25 Orange  8.6 Orange 6
```

I would like to get the difference the two df by comparing those columns in common only.
So the result I expect to get is

```
         Date   Fruit   Num   Color A
4  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1     Red 5
5  2013-11-25  Orange   8.6  Orange 6
```

Is there a way to do so? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you get the column names of df1

```
df1_columns = df1.columns # ["Date", "Fruit", "Num", "Color"]
```

Now you create a new df2 dataframe with only df1 columns

```
df2_filtered = df2[df1_columns]
```

And now you can apply the solution from this other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20225110/comparing-two-dataframes-and-getting-the-differences).

```
#concatenate both dataframes
df = pd.concat([df1, df2_filtered])
df = df.reset_index(drop=True)

#group by
df_gpby = df.groupby(list(df.columns))

# get index of unique records
idx = [x[0] for x in df_gpby.groups.values() if len(x) == 1]

#filter
df.reindex(idx)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

If you **don't have duplicates** in `df1` or `df2[df1.columns]` you could try to use [`.drop_duplicates`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html) with `keep=False`:

```py
res = pd.concat([df1, df2[df1.columns]]).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```

Result for your sample dataframes:

```
         Date   Fruit   Num   Color
4  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1     Red
5  2013-11-25  Orange   8.6  Orange
```

PS: As far as I can see the other answer also covers only the non-duplicate case.

If you do **have duplicates** in `df1` or `df2[df1.columns]` and want to preserve them in the result you could try:

```py
res = pd.concat(
    [df1.drop_duplicates(), df2[df1.columns].drop_duplicates()]
).drop_duplicates(keep=False).merge(
    pd.concat([df1, df2[df1.columns]]), on=list(df1.columns), how="inner"
)
```

- First drop the duplicates in the originals, and then the duplicates on the concatenated dataframes: This will give you the rows that are not in both.
- Then fetch from the originals the right amount of rows by an inner merge with the result of the first step.

For example, if `df2` would look like

```
Date       Fruit  Num  Color  A
2013-11-24 Banana 22.1 Yellow 1 
2013-11-24 Orange  8.6 Orange 2
2013-11-24 Apple   7.6 Green  3 
2013-11-24 Celery 10.2 Green  4
2013-11-25 Apple  22.1 Red    5
2013-11-25 Apple  22.1 Red    5
2013-11-25 Orange  8.6 Orange 6
```

then the result would be

```
         Date   Fruit   Num   Color
0  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1     Red
1  2013-11-25   Apple  22.1     Red
2  2013-11-25  Orange   8.6  Orange
```

If you don't want to preserve the duplicates in the result then just do

```py
res = pd.concat(
    [df1.drop_duplicates(), df2[df1.columns].drop_duplicates()]
).drop_duplicates(keep=False)
```