# using pandas to compare large CSV files with different numbers of columns

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am new at python programming and I am trying to join two csv files with different numbers of columns. The aim is to find missing records and create a report with specific columns from the master column.

An example of two csv files copied directly from excel 
SAMPLE CSV 1(combine201709.csv)

```
start_time  end_time    aitechid    hh_village  grpdetails1/farmername  grpdetails1/farmermobile
2016-11-26T14:01:47.329+03  2016-11-26T14:29:05.042+03  AI00001 2447    KahsuGebru  919115604
2016-11-26T19:34:42.159+03  2016-11-26T20:39:27.430+03  936891238   2473    Moto Aleka  914370833
2016-11-26T12:13:23.094+03  2016-11-26T14:25:19.178+03  914127382   2390    Hagos   914039654
2016-11-30T14:31:28.223+03  2016-11-30T14:56:33.144+03  920784222
```

SAMPLE CSV 2 (combinedmissingrecords.csv)

```
farmermobile
941807851
946741296
9
920212218
915
939555303
961579437
919961811
100004123
972635273
918166831
961579437
922882638
100006273
919728710
30000739
920770648
100004727
963767487
915855665
932255143
923531603
0
931875236
918027506
8
916353266
918020303
924359729
934623027
916585963
960791618
988047183
100002632
300007241
918271897
300007238
918250712
```

I tried this, but was unable to get the expected output:

```
    import pandas as pd

normalize = lambda x: "%.4f" % float(x) # round
df = pd.read_csv("/media/dmogaka/DATA/week progress/week4/combine201709.csv", index_col=(0,1), usecols=(1, 2, 3,4),
                 header=None, converters=dict.fromkeys([1,2]))
df2 = pd.read_csv("/media/dmogaka/DATA/week progress/week4/combinedmissingrecords.csv", index_col=(0,1), usecols=(0),
                  header=None, converters=dict.fromkeys([1,2]))
result = df2.merge(df[['aitechid','grpdetails1/farmermobile','grpdetails1/farmername']],
         left_on='farmermobile', right_on='grpdetails1/farmermobile')
result.to_csv("/media/dmogaka/DATA/week progress/week4/output.csv", header=None) # write as csv
```

error message

```
/usr/bin/python3.5 "/media/dmogaka/DATA/Panda tut/test/test.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/dmogaka/DATA/Panda tut/test/test.py", line 7, in <module>
    header=None, converters=dict.fromkeys([1,2]))
  File "/home/dmogaka/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 655, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/dmogaka/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 405, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
  File "/home/dmogaka/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 764, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/home/dmogaka/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 985, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/home/dmogaka/.local/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1605, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 461, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__ (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:4968)
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Comparing two pandas dataframes for differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917545/comparing-two-pandas-dataframes-for-differences)

Comment: @MrE, I don't think it's a duplicate. If we have different # of columns `assert_frame_equal` will always be returning `AssertionError`

Comment: Can you post two small (3-5 rows) sample reproducible data sets and your desired resulting data set? Please read [how to make good reproducible pandas examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples) and edit your post correspondingly.

Comment: just guessing if yo uwant to compare dataframes, they should have the same format. So the first step is trim / adjust format to get comparable DFs, then compare as per the other post

Comment: @MrE, imagine that we want to see which rows are missing in first DF that are present in the second one...

Comment: @MaxU  i have updated data from the two csv files, i really need a solution that works

Comment: @MirieriMogaka, and what would be your desired data set?

Comment: @MaxU my desired data set is farmername, aitechid and  farmermobile(Primary Key)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
d2.merge(d1[['aitechid','grpdetails1/farmermobile','grpdetails1/farmername']], 
         left_on='farmermobile', right_on='grpdetails1/farmermobile')
```

or

```
d2.merge(d1[['aitechid','grpdetails1/farmermobile','grpdetails1/farmername']] \
          .rename(columns={'grpdetails1/farmermobile':'farmermobile'}))
```

Comment: i have tried your code but i keep getting the error message above @MaxU