# Python index() doesn't work

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list of dataframes like this one :

```
arr = [df1, df2, df3]
```

And I want to get a position of element in this list:

```
position_of_df2 = arr.index(df2)
```

But python gives error on this line:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What Im doing wrong?
PS what is the best way to get index of dataframe in array? Only iteration?

Comment: Not answering your question but you perhaps could solve your problem by storing your data frames in a dict with the key as the name, this would allow you to easily access them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`list.index` works by checking **equality** of your input with elements from the list and looking for `True`. It then returns the index of the first match.

Testing equality of 2 dataframes returns a dataframe:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]])

print(df1 == df2)

      0     1
0  True  True
```

The truthness of the result is ambiguous:

```
print(bool(df1 == df2))

# ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous.
# Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

**Option 1**

In my opinion, the best way to check if you have the correct dataframe is to use an ordered dictionary and define keys (preferably, use descriptive names as keys):

```
from collections import OrderedDict

o = OrderedDict([(1, df1), (2, df2), (3, df3)])

print(list(o.keys()).index(2))  # 1
```

**Option 2**

Use a generator expression with `is`, which returns `True` only if 2 variables point to the same object:

```
lst = [df1, df2, df3]

res = next(i for i, j in enumerate(lst) if j is df2)  # 1
```

Comment: Therefore, iterate manually and check identity (with `is`) instead.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer of @jpp above, also quoting from the answer, https://stackoverflow.com/a/19918849/423725, improvised a solution.

```
df1 = pandas.DataFrame([1, 2])
df2 = pandas.DataFrame([3, 4])
df3 = pandas.DataFrame([5, 6])

arr = [df1, df2, df3]

def isEqual(df1, df2):
    from pandas.util.testing import assert_frame_equal

    try:
        assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
        return True
    except:  # appeantly AssertionError doesn't catch all
        return False

def indexDF(df, arr):
    for index, dataframe in enumerate(arr):
        if isEqual(df, dataframe):
            return index

indexDF(df2, arr)
# 1
```

Comment: The only issue is if `df1 = df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2]])`, then both dataframes will be considered the same for indexing purposes. I'm not *sure* that's what OP wants, but it should be noted.

Comment: @jpp That's correct. It's confusing to have same dataframes with different id's. Question is, am I looking for the closest one or the one that exactly matches with specified df.

Comment: yeah, it's about the first occurence in array. thank you @BcK for this answer