# Getting a list of indices where pandas boolean series is True

Tags: python, pandas, boolean, series, boolean-indexing

I have a pandas series with boolean entries.  I would like to get a list of indices where the values are `True`.

For example the input `pd.Series([True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True])`

should yield the output `[0,2,3,7]`.

I can do it with a list comprehension, but is there something cleaner or faster?

Comment: A better testcase is `s = pd.Series([True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True], index=list('ABCDEFGH'))`. Expected output: `Index(['A', 'C', 'D', 'H'], ...)`. Since some solutions (esp. all the np functions) drop the index and use the autonumber index.

Comment: ...if we have a named index, it's usually very undesirable to drop it.

Answer (score 177):

#### Using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```
>>> s = pd.Series([True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True])
>>> s[s].index
Int64Index([0, 2, 3, 7], dtype='int64')
```

If need a `np.array` object, get the `.values`

```
>>> s[s].index.values
array([0, 2, 3, 7])
```

---

#### Using [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)

```
>>> np.nonzero(s)
(array([0, 2, 3, 7]),)
```

---

#### Using [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html)

```
>>> np.flatnonzero(s)
array([0, 2, 3, 7])
```

---

#### Using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
>>> np.where(s)[0]
array([0, 2, 3, 7])
```

---

#### Using [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html)

```
>>> np.argwhere(s).ravel()
array([0, 2, 3, 7])
```

---

#### Using [`pd.Series.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.index.html#pandas.Series.index)

```
>>> s.index[s]
array([0, 2, 3, 7])
```

---

#### Using Python's built-in [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

```
>>> [*filter(s.get, s.index)]
[0, 2, 3, 7]
```

---

#### Using list comprehension

```
>>> [i for i in s.index if s[i]]
[0, 2, 3, 7]
```

Comment: what if the series indices has label instead index-range?

Comment: @pyd then you can use options referred to in the answer as `Boolean Indexing`, `pd.Series.index`. `filter` and `list comprehension` — basically NOT the numpy ones

Comment: @Dahn I did not understand your answer. Can you explain further?

Comment: @MattS If the series have index **other than** range index, then any methods listed in `rafaelc`'s answer that are based on numpy won't' work, as numpy will forget the indices upon conversion. I therefore listed the methods that do still work in that case. Does that work for you?

Comment: I think we should also mention here `.where()` method. Check here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html

Comment: TIMTOWTDI FTW!!

Answer (score 32):

As an addition to [rafaelc's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52173171/5299750), here are the according times (from quickest to slowest) for the following setup

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
s = pd.Series([x > 0.5 for x in np.random.random(size=1000)])
```

#### Using [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```py
>>> timeit np.where(s)[0]
12.7 µs ± 77.4 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

#### Using [`np.flatnonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.flatnonzero.html)

```py
>>> timeit np.flatnonzero(s)
18 µs ± 508 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

---

#### Using [`pd.Series.index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.index.html#pandas.Series.index)

The time difference to boolean indexing was really surprising to me, since the boolean indexing is usually more used.

```py
>>> timeit s.index[s]
82.2 µs ± 38.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

---

#### Using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing)

```py
>>> timeit s[s].index
1.75 ms ± 2.16 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

If you need a `np.array` object, get the `.values`

```py
>>> timeit s[s].index.values
1.76 ms ± 3.1 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

If you need a slightly easier to read version <-- not in original answer

```py
>>> timeit s[s==True].index
1.89 ms ± 3.52 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

---

#### Using [`pd.Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) <-- not in original answer

```py
>>> timeit s.where(s).dropna().index
2.22 ms ± 3.32 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> timeit s.where(s == True).dropna().index
2.37 ms ± 2.19 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

#### Using [`pd.Series.mask`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.mask.html) <-- not in original answer

```py
>>> timeit s.mask(s).dropna().index
2.29 ms ± 1.43 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

>>> timeit s.mask(s == True).dropna().index
2.44 ms ± 5.82 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

#### Using list comprehension

```py
>>> timeit [i for i in s.index if s[i]]
13.7 ms ± 40.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

#### Using Python's built-in [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)

```py
>>> timeit [*filter(s.get, s.index)]
14.2 ms ± 28.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

---

#### Using [`np.nonzero`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html) <-- did not work out of the box for me

```py
>>> timeit np.nonzero(s)
ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 1000.
```

---

#### Using [`np.argwhere`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argwhere.html) <-- did not work out of the box for me

```py
>>> timeit np.argwhere(s).ravel()
ValueError: Length of passed values is 1, index implies 1000.
```

Answer (score 5):

Also works:
`s.where(lambda x: x).dropna().index`, and
it has the advantage of being easy to chain pipe - if your series is being computed on the fly, you don't need to assign it to a variable.

Note that if `s` is computed from `r`: `s = cond(r)`
than you can also use: `r.where(lambda x: cond(x)).dropna().index`.

Comment: *"it has the advantage of being easy to chain"* -- You can pass a function as an indexer, so this works: `s[lambda x: x].index`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `pipe` or `loc` to chain the operation, this is helpful when `s` is an intermediate result and you don't want to name it.

```py
s = pd.Series([True, False, True, True, False, False, False, True], index=list('ABCDEFGH'))

out = s.pipe(lambda s_: s_[s_].index)
# or
out = s.pipe(lambda s_: s_[s_]).index
# or
out = s.loc[lambda s_: s_].index
```

```
print(out)

Index(['A', 'C', 'D', 'H'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Regular indexing works: `s[lambda s_: s_].index`

Comment: With MultiIndex, one can also use an extra step to convert to slice-able array: `out = np.array(s.loc[lambda s_: s_].index.to_list())`