# Comparing two columns using Pandas (or numpy) and calculate percentage difference

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Disclaimer: I'm learning to develop in Python and I know that way of coding is probably like trash but I plan to keep improving while creating programs.

So I'm trying to build a scraper to check for specific flights prices daily with Selenium and that part of the code is already done. Origin, destination, first flight date, second flight date and price will be saved every day. I'm saving those data into a file and then comparing if there were any changes in price.

My aim is to make if there is change in price by more than an X percentage and then to print a message into the script for every compared flight.

```
import pandas as pd
import os.path
import numpy as np

#This are just sample data before integrating Selenium values
price = 230
departuredate = '20/02/2020'
returndate = '20/02/2020'
fromm = 'BOS'
to = 'JFK'

price2 = 630
departuredate2 = '20/02/2020'
returndate2 = '20/02/2020'
fromm2= 'CDG'
to2= 'JFK'
#End of sample data


flightdata = {'From': [fromm, fromm2], 'To': [to,to2], 'Departure date': [departuredate,departuredate2], 'Return date': [returndate,returndate2], 'Price': [price,price2]}

df = pd.DataFrame(flightdata, columns= ['From', 'To', 'Departure date', 'Return date', 'Price'])


#Check if the script is running for the first time
if os.path.exists('flightstoday.xls') == True:
 os.remove("flightsyesterday.xls")
 os.rename('flightstoday.xls', 'flightsyesterday.xls') #Rename the flights scraped fromm yesterday
 df.to_csv('flightstoday.xls', mode='a', header=True, sep='\t')
else:
 df.to_csv('flightstoday.xls', mode='w', header=True, sep='\t')

#Work with two dataframes
flightsyesterday = pd.read_csv("flightsyesterday.xls",sep='\t') 
flightstoday = pd.read_csv("flightstoday.xls",sep='\t')
```

What I'm missing is how to compare the column 'Price' and print a message saying that for the row X with 'From', 'To', 'Departure date', 'Return date' the flight has changed by an X percentage.

I have tried this code but it only adds a column to flighstoday file but not the percentage and of course doesn't print there was any change in price.

```
flightstoday['PriceDiff'] = np.where(vueloshoy['Price'] == vuelosayer['Price'], 0, vueloshoy['Price'] - vuelosayer['Price'])
```

Any help for this newbie will be greatly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: I just fixed some of the code when copying it.
Dataframe is same as you can see in the code.

Comment: okay you have a price column for BOS to JFK and CFG to JFK what are you comparing exactly? can you add an expected output? if its hard to create just do it in excel and paste it as text

Comment: So I will have two text files/dataframes

Let's suppose I scrap for two days, flights from yesterda are like this:

 From To Departure date Return date Price
0 BOS JFK 20/02/2020 20/02/2020 230
1 CDG JFK 20/02/2020 20/02/2020 630

Flights from today are like this:

 From To Departure date Return date Price
0 BOS JFK 20/02/2020 20/02/2020 230
1 CDG JFK 20/02/2020 20/02/2020 200

So now the column Price on row 1 is different so I would like to calculate a percentage and send a message stating that the value changedby an x percent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I've gathered, I think this is what you're intending to do.

```py
import pandas as pd
import os.path
import numpy as np

# This are just sample data before integrating Selenium values
price = 230
departuredate = '20/02/2020'
returndate = '20/02/2020'
fromm = 'BOS'
to = 'JFK'

price2 = 630
departuredate2 = '20/02/2020'
returndate2 = '20/02/2020'
fromm2 = 'CDG'
to2 = 'JFK'

# Create second set of prices
price3 = 250
price4 = 600

# Generate data to construct DataFrames
today_flightdata = {'From': [fromm, fromm2], 'To': [to, to2], 'Departure date': [
    departuredate, departuredate2], 'Return date': [returndate, returndate2], 'Price': [price, price2]}
yesterday_flightdata = {'From': [fromm, fromm2], 'To': [to, to2], 'Departure date': [
    departuredate, departuredate2], 'Return date': [returndate, returndate2], 'Price': [price3, price4]}

# Create dataframes for yesterday and today
today = pd.DataFrame(today_flightdata, columns=[
                     'From', 'To', 'Departure date', 'Return date', 'Price'])
yesterday = pd.DataFrame(yesterday_flightdata, columns=[
                         'From', 'To', 'Departure date', 'Return date', 'Price'])

# Determine changes
today['price_change'] = (
    today['Price'] - yesterday['Price']) / yesterday['Price'] * 100.

# Determine indices of all rows where price_change > threshold
threshold = 1.0
today['exceeds_threshold'] = abs(today['price_change']) >= threshold
exceed_indices = today['exceeds_threshold'][today['exceeds_threshold']].index

# Print out those entries that exceed threshold
for idx in exceed_indices:
    row = today.iloc[idx]
    print('Flight from {} to {} leaving on {} and returning on {} has changed by {}%'.format(
        row['From'], row['To'], row['Departure date'], row['Return date'], row['price_change']))
```

Output:

`Flight from CDG to JFK leaving on 20/02/2020 and returning on 20/02/2020 has changed by 5.0%`

I learned the syntax to calculate `exceed_indices` from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173161/getting-a-list-of-indices-where-pandas-boolean-series-is-true/52173171)

Comment: Thank you for your code! It looks good but ideally the threshold should be able to detect negative values too, e. g. priced changes +5% or - 5% both should trigger it if it is 5.

Comment: You can use the `abs()` function when comparing to the threshold to ignore the sign. I've edited my post.

Comment: I was about to comment that's the solution I found. Thank you :)

Comment: You're welcome :) Make sure to mark this answer as the solution so others know the issue is resolved.