# Get pandas series labels of true values without storing the series in a temp variable

Tags: python, pandas

Input:

```
pd.Series([True, False, True, False], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
```

Desired result:

```
['a', 'c']  # can be in pd.Series or np.array format, doesn't matter.
```

**But** I want a solution which does not store the series in a temporary variable, e.g.

```
s = pd.Series([True, False, True, False], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])
s[s == True].index
```

stores the series in s, and uses it twice.

The solution I'm looking for is like

```
np.where(s)
```

But returns the label of the true values, rather than their integer indices.

#### Notes:

This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173161/getting-a-list-of-indices-where-pandas-boolean-series-is-true/52173171), but more specific.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I always pass to `loc`

```
pd.Series([True, False, True, False], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).loc[lambda x : x].index
Index(['a', 'c'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Aha! Great answer. So there's no builtin for this in pandas?

Comment: @AlexLenail I do not think so ~