# return pandas series where value is true

Tags: python, pandas

Given this

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.Series([True, True, False, False],
    index=['2019-01-01','2019-01-02','2019-01-03','2019-01-04'])

data[data]     # why this works?
data[-data]
```

Is there any other way besides the above.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting a list of indices where pandas boolean series is True](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52173161/getting-a-list-of-indices-where-pandas-boolean-series-is-true)

Comment: Search for boolean indexing: on the [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).

Comment: Is your question another way to return where the series is True (i.e another way to do the same thing as `data[data]`)? Or are you wanting to know how to return a series where the value is False (I am assuming `data[-data]` is your attempt at this)?

Comment: I'm missing something here. I can understand data[0], and I can understand something like linq where data.where(values == false).  But why data[data] can return all record with true values.  You mentioned because it is a Boolean index, I thought the index is actually the date string.  Just trying to get my head around it.