# Python: How to get position of pandas.series element where conditions exist?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, getlocation

I have a `numpy.ndarrays: x,y`:

```
>>> x = np.ndarray(shape=(10,), buffer=np.array([0.9902, 0.9394, 0.839,  0.8574, 0.9174, 0.8742, 0.8955, 0.9196, 0.9388, 0.9602]), dtype=float)

[0.9902 0.9394 0.839  0.8574 0.9174 0.8742 0.8955 0.9196 0.9388 0.9602]

>>> y = np.ndarray(shape=(10,), buffer=np.array([0.956, 0.884, 0.875, 0.880, 0.865, 0.870, 0.861, 0.817, 0.771, 0.727]), dtype=float)

[0.956, 0.884, 0.875, 0.880, 0.865, 0.870, 0.861, 0.817, 0.771, 0.727]
```

and series `edge_or_not`:

```
>>> d = {'2020-03-17 04:39:00+03:00': 0,
          '2020-03-17 04:40:00+03:00': 1,
          '2020-03-17 04:41:00+03:00': 0,
          '2020-03-17 04:42:00+03:00': -1,
          '2020-03-17 04:43:00+03:00': 0,
          '2020-03-17 04:44:00+03:00': 0,
          '2020-03-17 04:45:00+03:00': 1,
          '2020-03-17 04:46:00+03:00': -1,
          '2020-03-17 04:47:00+03:00': -1,
          '2020-03-17 04:48:00+03:00': -1}

>>> edge_or_not = pd.Series(data=d)

2020-03-17 04:39:00+03:00    0
2020-03-17 04:40:00+03:00    1
2020-03-17 04:41:00+03:00    0
2020-03-17 04:42:00+03:00   -1
2020-03-17 04:43:00+03:00    0
2020-03-17 04:44:00+03:00    0
2020-03-17 04:45:00+03:00    1
2020-03-17 04:46:00+03:00   -1
2020-03-17 04:47:00+03:00   -1
2020-03-17 04:48:00+03:00   -1
dtype: int64
```

And I'm getting `up_edge_x`, `up_edge_y`, `down_edge_x`, `down_edge_y` like this:

```
>>> up_edge_x = x[edge_or_not > 0]

array([0.9394, 0.8955])

>>> up_edge_y = y[edge_or_not > 0]

array([0.884, 0.861])

>>> down_edge_x = x[edge_or_not < 0]

array([0.8574, 0.9196, 0.9388, 0.9602])

>>> down_edge_y = y[edge_or_not < 0]

array([0.88 , 0.817, 0.771, 0.727])
```

And `all_edges_x`, `all_edges_y`:

```
>>> all_edges_x = x[edge_or_not != 0]

array([0.9394, 0.8574, 0.8955, 0.9196, 0.9388, 0.9602])

>>> all_edges_y = y[edge_or_not != 0]

array([0.884, 0.88 , 0.861, 0.817, 0.771, 0.727])
```

And then creating DataFrames:

```
>>> up_edge = pd.DataFrame({'y':up_edge_y}, index=up_edge_x)

            y   (pos)
0.9394  0.884       0
0.8955  0.861       1

>>> down_edge = pd.DataFrame({'y':down_edge_y}, index=down_edge_x)

            y   (pos)
0.8574  0.880       0
0.9196  0.817       1
0.9388  0.771       2
0.9602  0.727       3
```

All I need is creating `all_edges DataFrame` where will be 3 columns: `'y'`, `'edge'`, `'pos'`

```
>>> all_edges = pd.DataFrame({'y':all_edges_y, 'edge':edge_or_not[edge_or_not != 0].to_numpy(), 
                         'pos':???},
                          index=all_edges_x)
```

So that after all `all_edges DataFrame` must look like this:

```
            y  edge  pos
0.9394  0.884     1    0
0.8574  0.880    -1    0
0.8955  0.861     1    1
0.9196  0.817    -1    1
0.9388  0.771    -1    2
0.9602  0.727    -1    3
```

How to calculate 3rd column `pos`, that I can links to `all_edges` from `up_edge` and `down_edge` DataFrames like in below stupid example:

```
>>> down_x1 = 0.9602
>>> loc = down_edge.index.get_loc(down_x1)
>>> edges = all_edges.loc[all_edges['pos']==loc]['edge']
>>> print(edges)

0.9602   -1
Name: edge, dtype: int64
```

And I've got a second question: How to get array of locations another DataFrame?
Like this:

```
>>> locations = down_edge.index.get_loc(#mb all indexes)

[0, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52173171/4687565

Comment: @Dimitry, Я обновил пост. И пока я это делал - осознал, чтобы посчитать третий столбец можно вообще не привязываться к первым двум датафреймам. А также понял, что сразу не уточнил, что было бы неплохо понимать как можно получить массив из позиций pandas.DataFrame? Что собственно я и указал как второй вопрос. By the way, спасбо за комментарий.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
up_edge_x = x[edge_or_not > 0]
up_edge_y = y[edge_or_not > 0]

down_edge_x = x[edge_or_not < 0]
down_edge_y = y[edge_or_not < 0]

all_edges_x = x[edge_or_not != 0]
all_edges_y = y[edge_or_not != 0]
```

Create `Series` by ranges with index by `up_edge_x, down_edge_x` first:

```
up_edge = pd.Series(range(len(up_edge_x)), index=up_edge_x, name='pos')
down_edge = pd.Series(range(len(down_edge_x)), index=down_edge_x, name='pos')
print (up_edge)
0.9394    0
0.8955    1
Name: pos, dtype: int64

print (down_edge)
0.8574    0
0.9196    1
0.9388    2
0.9602    3
Name: pos, dtype: int64
```

Then join together:

```
pos = pd.concat([up_edge, down_edge])
print (pos)
0.9394    0
0.8955    1
0.8574    0
0.9196    1
0.9388    2
0.9602    3
Name: pos, dtype: int64
```

And last map new column:

```
all_edges = pd.DataFrame({'y':all_edges_y,
                          'edge':edge_or_not[edge_or_not != 0].to_numpy(), 
                          'pos': pd.Index(all_edges_x).map(pos)},
                          index=all_edges_x)


print (all_edges)
            y  edge  pos
0.9394  0.884     1    0
0.8574  0.880    -1    0
0.8955  0.861     1    1
0.9196  0.817    -1    1
0.9388  0.771    -1    2
0.9602  0.727    -1    3
```

Comment: 0) I edited the post.  1) If using `np.where` so I have 2 conditions `edge_or_not > 0` and `edge_or_not < 0`.   2) I don't know how to calculate positionS_in_up_edge and positionS_in_down_edge, so I pointed it as 2nd question. Thank you for your answer.

Comment: @RenNingen - Can you check now?

Answer (score 0):

I thought I might not get attached to `up_edge` and `down_edge` and just proceed as follows:

```
>>> all_edges['pos'] = all_edges.groupby(all_edges['edge']).cumcount()
```

Pre-creating a DataFrame `all_edges` like this:

```
>>> all_edges = pd.DataFrame({'y':all_edges_y, 'edge':edge_or_not[edge_or_not != 0].to_numpy()}, index=all_edges_x)
```