# compare 2 csv file and find out missing, inserted data and modified data using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

Using Pandas, I want to compare 2 csv files. Both files have same data but in 2nd file, some rows will be deleted, some will be inserted and some will be modified. I want to compare both the files and find out the deleted, inserted and modified row.

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917545/comparing-two-pandas-dataframes-for-differences

Comment: Thank you, I will check out .

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is to use:

```
df1[~df1.apply(tuple,1).isin(df2.apply(tuple,1))]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment, but  this shows only the difference. I want to know the inserted rows too.