# How do I overload `__eq__` to compare pandas DataFrames and Series?

Tags: python, pandas, overloading, equality

For clarity I will extract an excerpt from my code and use general names.  I have a class `Foo()` that stores a DataFrame to an attribute.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.util.testing as pdt

class Foo():

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar                                     # dict of dicts
        self.df = pd.DataFrame(bar)                        # pandas object     

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            return self.__dict__ == other.__dict__
        return NotImplemented

    def __ne__(self, other):
        result = self.__eq__(other)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            return result
        return not result
```

However, when I try to compare two instances of `Foo`, I get an excepetion related to the ambiguity of comparing two DataFrames (the comparison should work fine without the 'df' key in `Foo.__dict__`).

```
d1 = {'A' : pd.Series([1, 2], index=['a', 'b']),
      'B' : pd.Series([1, 2], index=['a', 'b'])}
d2 = d1.copy()

foo1 = Foo(d1)
foo2 = Foo(d2)

foo1.bar                                                   # dict
foo1.df                                                    # pandas DataFrame

foo1 == foo2                                               # ValueError 

[Out] ValueError: The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

Fortunately, pandas has utility functions for asserting whether two DataFrames or Series are true.  I'd like to use this function's comparison operation if possible.

```
pdt.assert_frame_equal(pd.DataFrame(d1), pd.DataFrame(d2)) # no raises
```

There are a few options to resolve the comparison of two `Foo` instances:

1. compare a copy of `__dict__`, where `new_dict` lacks the df key
2. delete the df key from `__dict__` (not ideal)
3. don't compare `__dict__`, but only parts of it contained in a tuple
4. **overload the `__eq__` to facilitate pandas DataFrame comparisons**

The last option seems the most robust in the long-run, but I am not sure of the best approach. In the end, **I would like to refactor `__eq__` to compare all items from `Foo.__dict__`, including DataFrames (and Series).**  Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Comment: why don't you just make subclasses for dataframe and series, and write your own `__eq__` function?  You can super the original for other cases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution from these threads

[Comparing two pandas dataframes for differences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917545/comparing-two-pandas-dataframes-for-differences)

[Pandas DataFrames with NaNs equality comparison](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322506/pandas-dataframes-with-nans-equality-comparison)

```
def df_equal(self):
    try:
        assert_frame_equal(csvdata, csvdata_old)
        return True
    except:
        return False
```

For a dictionary of dataframes:

```
def df_equal(df1, df2):
    try:
        assert_frame_equal(df1, df2)
        return True
    except:
        return False

def __eq__(self, other):
    if self.df.keys() != other.keys():
        return False
    for k in self.df.keys():
        if not df_equal(self.df[k], other[k]):
            return False
    return True
```

Comment: I appreciate the links.  Seems close, but I need `__eq__` to handle all attributes contained in `foo.__dict__`, i.e. `df` and `bar`.  This looks like it will only handle DataFrames.

Comment: gotcha. you might have to just implement the individual comparisons yourself. I updated the answer with an idea, but you'll have to decide exactly what equality means in terms of your objects.

Comment: Don't forget to upvote useful answers!! Usually .keys is referenced as .columns for clarity. I'm not *sure* the above will work as usually df[k] is a Series (`assert_frame_equal` works on DataFrames only).

Comment: Yes, this is much closer.  I was hoping to handle Series as well, but your ideas inspired another answer that solves my problem completely.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The following code seems to satisfy my original question completely.  It handles both pandas `DataFrames` and `Series`.  Simplifications are welcome.

The trick here is that `__eq__` has been implemented to compare `__dict__` and pandas objects separately.  The truthiness of each is finally compared and the result returned.  Something interesting and exploited here, `and` returns the second value if the the first value is `True`.

The idea for using error handling and an external comparison function was inspired by an answer submitted by @ate50eggs.  Many thanks.

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas.util.testing as pdt

def ndframe_equal(ndf1, ndf2):
    try:
        if isinstance(ndf1, pd.DataFrame) and isinstance(ndf2, pd.DataFrame):
            pdt.assert_frame_equal(ndf1, ndf2)
            #print('DataFrame check:', type(ndf1), type(ndf2))
        elif  isinstance(ndf1, pd.Series) and isinstance(ndf2, pd.Series):
            pdt.assert_series_equal(ndf1, ndf2)
            #print('Series check:', type(ndf1), type(ndf2))
        return True
    except (ValueError, AssertionError, AttributeError):            
        return False


class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar                                     
        try:
            self.ndf = pd.DataFrame(bar)
        except(ValueError):
            self.ndf = pd.Series(bar)  

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, self.__class__):
            # Auto check attrs if assigned to DataFrames/Series, then add to list
            blacklisted  = [attr for attr in self.__dict__ if 
                              isinstance(getattr(self, attr), pd.DataFrame)
                              or isinstance(getattr(self, attr), pd.Series)]

            # Check DataFrames and Series
            for attr in blacklisted:
                ndf_eq = ndframe_equal(getattr(self, attr), 
                                          getattr(other, attr))

            # Ignore pandas objects; check rest of __dict__ and build new dicts
            self._dict = {
                key: value 
                for key, value in self.__dict__.items()
                if key not in blacklisted}
            other._dict = {
                key: value 
                for key, value in other.__dict__.items()
                if key not in blacklisted}
            return ndf_eq and self._dict == other._dict    # order is important 
        return NotImplemented             

    def __ne__(self, other):
        result = self.__eq__(other)
        if result is NotImplemented:
            return result
        return not result
```

Testing the latter code on `DataFrames`.

```
# Data for DataFrames
d1 = {'A' : pd.Series([1, 2], index=['a', 'b']),
      'B' : pd.Series([1, 2], index=['a', 'b'])}
d2 = d1.copy()
d3 = {'A' : pd.Series([1, 2], index=['abc', 'b']),
      'B' : pd.Series([9, 0], index=['abc', 'b'])}

# Test DataFrames
foo1 = Foo(d1)
foo2 = Foo(d2)

foo1.bar                                         # dict of Series
foo1.ndf                                         # pandas DataFrame

foo1 == foo2                                     # triggers _dict 
#foo1.__dict__['_dict']
#foo1._dict

foo1 == foo2                                     # True                
foo1 != foo2                                     # False 
not foo1 == foo2                                 # False               
not foo1 != foo2                                 # True
foo2 = Foo(d3)                                                     

foo1 == foo2                                     # False
foo1 != foo2                                     # True
not foo1 == foo2                                 # True
not foo1 != foo2                                 # False
```

Finally testing on another common pandas object, the `Series`.

```
# Data for Series
s1 = {'a' : 0., 'b' : 1., 'c' : 2.}
s2 = s1.copy()
s3 = {'a' : 0., 'b' : 4, 'c' : 5}

# Test Series
foo3 = Foo(s1)
foo4 = Foo(s2)

foo3.bar                                         # dict 
foo4.ndf                                         # pandas Series

foo3 == foo4                                     # True
foo3 != foo4                                     # False
not foo3 == foo4                                 # False
not foo3 != foo4                                 # True

foo4 = Foo(s3)
foo3 == foo4                                     # False    
foo3 != foo4                                     # True 
not foo3 == foo4                                 # True    
not foo3 != foo4                                 # False
```