# Pandas DataFrame equality - index numbering

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas

Does Index numbering matter in testing dataframe equality? I have 2 identical dataframes with exactly the same data and columns. The only difference is that the index numbers for each row is different and equals methods returns a False. How can I get around this? Here are my data frames

```
   A   B
0  87  54
1  87  75
2  87  22
3  87  69

     A   B
418  87  69
107  87  54
108  87  75
250  87  22
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Pandas DataFrames with NaNs equality comparison](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322506/pandas-dataframes-with-nans-equality-comparison)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.array_equal` to check the values, however the ordering is important, so in your example you have to sort by the index first.

```
In [11]: df1
Out[11]:
    A   B
0  87  54
1  87  75
2  87  22
3  87  69

In [12]: df2
Out[12]:
      A   B
418  87  69
107  87  54
108  87  75
250  87  22

In [13]: df3 = df2.sort()

In [14]: df3
Out[14]:
      A   B
107  87  54
108  87  75
250  87  22
418  87  69

In [15]: np.array_equal(df1, df3)
Out[15]: True
```

---

Note: You can't compare df1 and df2 as they have different indexes:

```
In [21]: df1 == df2
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled DataFrame object
```

You can reset the index, but be aware that an exception can be raised for that reason:

```
In [22]: df3.reset_index(drop=True)
Out[22]:
    A   B
0  87  54
1  87  75
2  87  22
3  87  69

In [23]: np.all(df1 == df3.reset_index(drop=True))
Out[23]: True
```

Another option is to have a try and except block around `assert_frame_equals`:

```
In [24]: pd.util.testing.assert_frame_equal(df1, df3.reset_index(drop=True))
```

as in this [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19322766/1240268).

As Jeff points out you can use .equals, which does this:

```
In [25]: df1.equals(df3.reset_index(drop=True))
Out[25]: True
```

Comment: check_names=False does not work here for some reason. Sorting idea is good! I am trying them out and will post an update (and accept your answer)

Comment: `check_names` checks the index names I think, which shouldn't affect your case since you don't have any index names.

Comment: Oh, did you mean to use assert after resetting index? It does not work without dropping index.

Comment: @AndyHayden we have had ``.equals(...)`` for a while :)

Comment: @Jeff not sure how I missed that when tab completing earlier! :)