# drop duplicates with Nan

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates

I am using drop_duplicates on a df with Twitter users.

I want to delete duplicates.
I have 2 lines which represent the exact same user. But Python does not recognize it as such for NaN values in the description field.

In other words, the test `W.iloc[10,8]==W.iloc[11,8]` return False (column 8 is description and lines and 11 are the duplicated rows). At the same time `np.isnan(W.iloc[10,8])` returns a True as does `np.isnan(W.iloc[11,8])`.

As such, the function drop_duplictaes, does not work for these 2 lines.

Any idea of what is happening?

Here goes the 2 lines

thanks for helping

Mauro

```
                        id           created_at lang   screen_name  name  \
226080  710412633443332096  2016-03-17 10:29:05   en  Mich00299495  Mich   
226081  710412633443332096  2016-03-17 10:29:05   en  Mich00299495  Mich   

                location default_profile default_profile_image description  \
226080  Grenoble, France            True                  True         NaN   
226081  Grenoble, France            True                  True         NaN   

        followers_count  ...    geo_enabled  \
226080              2.0  ...          False   
226081              2.0  ...          False   

                                  profile_image_url_https protected time_zone  \
226080  https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_i...     False       NaN   
226081  https://abs.twimg.com/sticky/default_profile_i...     False       NaN   

       verified favourites_count  statuses_count   sex name_F name_M  
226080    False              0.0             0.0  none   none   none  
226081    False              0.0             0.0  none   none   none
```

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322506/pandas-dataframes-with-nans-equality-comparison

Comment: `NaN` values cannot be compared using equality operator, you need to consider whether to fill those with some sensible value, after which `drop_duplicates` will then work

Comment: For me drop_duplicates with `NaN` works perfectly. What return `print (W.iloc[10]==W.iloc[11])` False values are only for NaN values or there is at least one another `False`?  You can test it by `print (W.iloc[10:12].T)`?

Comment: Hello my friend. Thanks for helping again

Comment: I must tell you that I am not proficient with Python. I am learning

Comment: print (W.iloc[0]==W.iloc[1])
id                          True
created_at                  True
lang                        True
screen_name                 True
name                        True
location                    True
default_profile             True
default_profile_image       True
description                False
followers_count             True
friends_count               True
geo_enabled                 True
profile_image_url_https     True
protected                   True
time_zone                  False
verified                    True

Comment: It is not really readable in the way I posted it.

Comment: Reformulating, it says that time_zone  and description of the 2 lines are not the same

Comment: All the other fields are the same (name, id, screen name etc...) as it must be as it is actually the same user

Comment: The description and time_zone fields are nan in both lines

Comment: I do not understand

Comment: By the way, I am working with python 3. Could this explain something?

Comment: Now I am even more confused: in the console, if i try:  data = pd.DataFrame({'k1': ['one'] * 5 + ['two'] * 6, 'k2': [1, np.nan,1,np.nan, 2, 3, 3, 4,np.nan, 4,np.nan]}) and then data.drop_duplicates() It works properly and drops the duplicated line

Comment: I am really confused now