# Compare 2 dataframes, return only differing cells, treating NaNs as equal

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, compare, nan

Thanks to stack overflow comments I created a little function that compares two dataframes using pandas.

```
 # sample data frames
 a1 = pd.DataFrame([{'_id' : '71', 'datum': '2009-11-30', 'width':'wide'},
  {'_id' : '71', 'datum': np.nan, 'width':'wide'},])

 a2 = pd.DataFrame([{'_id' : '71', 'datum': '2009-11-30', 'width':'wide'},
  {'_id' : 'A', 'datum': np.nan, 'width':'wide'},])

 a3 = pd.DataFrame([{'_id' : '71', 'datum': '2009-11-30', 'width':'wide'},
  {'_id' : 'A', 'datum': np.nan, 'width':'wider'},])


# compare function
def dfCompare(a,b):
    if a.equals(b) == True:      
        print "no differences detected"
    else:
        df = pd.concat([a,b])
        if not df.drop_duplicates(keep=False).empty:
            return df.drop_duplicates(keep=False)
        else: 
            print "no differences detected"

dfCompare(a1,a2)
```

How to modify the result such, that 
a) either only the cells are shown that differ, e.g.

```
  dfCompare(a1,a2)
```

[image]

b) or to "mark" (e.g. highlight, or format values bold,...) the cells with differing values

```
dfCompare(a1,a3)
```

[image]

Thanks for any help and thoughts!

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively straightforward, but you have inadvertently (or perhaps advertently) included a comparison that makes this a little tricky - and that is the comparison of NaNs where you want `NaN == NaN` to be evaluated as True.  But as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322506/pandas-dataframes-with-nans-equality-comparison) and subsequent answers show, `NaN == NaN` evaluates as False.

So, knowing that, and not providing a highlighted indication (because my terminal only prints in black and white, and you don't specify what you're using to view color formatting), here's the best I can provide (simply adding an " - X" to those that do not match):

```
a1[(a1 != a3) & ((a1 == a1) & (a3 == a3))] += ' - X'
```

Comment: Ah, thanks for the explanation. As a beginner I did not know this about NaN == NaN. Thanks for your code, but it gives me the error "Could not compare [' - X'] with block values". Concerning highlighting: the idea was, if always the complete row is shown, somehow visibly enhance the non-matching cells. E.g. with colouring the cell, or whatever is easiest.