# Replace the value in a column with the value of another column Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame, with columns `col1`, `col2`, and `col3`. I would like to replace `col2` with the value of `col3` if `col3` is not null; otherwise, skip the row.

input

```
col1  col2   col3 
   1     2    nan
   4     5    nan
   6     7      8
   1     0      9
```

output

```
col1  col2   col3 
   1     2    nan
   4     5    nan
   6     8      8
   1     9      9
```

This is my code:

```py
for i, row in df.iterrows():
   if row['col3'] != np.nan:
       row['col2'] = row['col3']
   else:
       row['col2'] = row['col2']
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Please show your expected output.

Comment: From what it sounds like, you should be able to first filter your dataframe by whether col3 is NaN: `df[~df['col3'].isnan()]`, then apply your logic.

Comment: @ddejohn intead of `~df['col3'].isnan()` you can use `df['col3'].notna()`

Comment: Derp, yes, of course.

Comment: Note that `!= np.nan` will [never work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322506/pandas-dataframes-with-nans-equality-comparison).

Answer (score 2):

Use `.loc` and `.notna()`:

```
df.loc[df['col3'].notna(), 'col2'] = df['col3']
```

Output:

```
>>> df
   col1  col2  col3
0     1   2.0   NaN
1     4   5.0   NaN
2     6   8.0   8.0
3     1   9.0   9.0
```