# Python Pandas updating dataframe and counting the number of cells updated

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Lets say I am updating my dataframe with another dataframe (df2)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df=pd.DataFrame({'axis1': ['Unix','Window','Apple','Linux'],
                 'A': [1,np.nan,1,1],
                 'B': [1,np.nan,np.nan,1],
                 'C': [np.nan,1,np.nan,1],
                 'D': [1,np.nan,1,np.nan],
                 }).set_index(['axis1'])

print (df)

df2=pd.DataFrame({'axis1': ['Unix','Window','Apple','Linux','A'],
                 'A': [1,1,np.nan,np.nan,np.nan],
                 'E': [1,np.nan,1,1,1],
                 }).set_index(['axis1'])

df = df.reindex(columns=df2.columns.union(df.columns),
                index=df2.index.union(df.index))

df.update(df2)

print (df)
```

Is there a command to get the number of cells that were updated? (changed from Nan to 1)
I want to use this to track changes to my dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

There is no built in method in pandas I can think of, you would have to save the original df prior to the update and then compare, the trick is to ensure that `NaN` comparisons are treated the same as non-zero values, here df3 is a copy of df prior to the call to update:

```
In [104]:

df.update(df2)
df
Out[104]:
         A   B   C   D   E
axis1                     
A      NaN NaN NaN NaN   1
Apple    1 NaN NaN   1   1
Linux    1   1   1 NaN   1
Unix     1   1 NaN   1   1
Window   1 NaN   1 NaN NaN

[5 rows x 5 columns]
In [105]:

df3
Out[105]:
         A   B   C   D   E
axis1                     
A      NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
Apple    1 NaN NaN   1 NaN
Linux    1   1   1 NaN NaN
Unix     1   1 NaN   1 NaN
Window NaN NaN   1 NaN NaN

[5 rows x 5 columns]
In [106]:

# compare but notice that NaN comparison returns True
df!=df3
Out[106]:
            A      B      C      D     E
axis1                                   
A        True   True   True   True  True
Apple   False   True   True  False  True
Linux   False  False  False   True  True
Unix    False  False   True  False  True
Window   True   True  False   True  True

[5 rows x 5 columns]

In [107]:
# use numpy count_non_zero for easy counting, note this gives wrong result
np.count_nonzero(df!=df3)
Out[107]:
16

In [132]:

~((df == df3) | (np.isnan(df) & np.isnan(df3)))
Out[132]:
            A      B      C      D      E
axis1                                    
A       False  False  False  False   True
Apple   False  False  False  False   True
Linux   False  False  False  False   True
Unix    False  False  False  False   True
Window   True  False  False  False  False

[5 rows x 5 columns]
In [133]:

np.count_nonzero(~((df == df3) | (np.isnan(df) & np.isnan(df3))))
Out[133]:
5
```

Comment: I submitted this as an enhancement for pandas https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/6891 Not sure why this was not in.

Comment: @ccsv don't know, I've never thought about needing this but I can see why this would be useful, it would be problematic and there would be a performance penalty if this was implemented for all methods that updated a dataframe/series/panel. I think that my method would generate a copy according to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819715/comparing-numpy-arrays-so-that-nans-compare-equal and comparing `NaN` is problematic

Comment: I use it to log changes. I believe performance problems can probably be solved using `cython`