# How to compare two dataframes ignoring column names?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Suppose I want to compare the content of two dataframes, but not the column names (or index names). **Is it possible to achieve this without renaming the columns?**

For example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2], 'B':[3,4]})
df_equal = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2], 'b':[3,4]})
df_diff = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1,2], 'B':[3,5]})
```

In this case, `df` is `df_equal` but different to `df_diff`, because the values in `df_equal` has the same content, but the ones in `df_diff`. Notice that ***the column names in `df_equal` are different***, but I still want to get a true value.

I have tried the following:

equals:

```
# Returns false because of the column names
df.equals(df_equal)
```

eq:

```
# doesn't work as it compares four columns (A,B,a,b) assuming nulls for the one that doesn't exist
df.eq(df_equal).all().all()
```

pandas.testing.assert_frame_equal:

```
# same as equals
pd.testing.assert_frame_equal(df, df_equal, check_names=False)
```

I thought that it was going to be possible to use the `assert_frame_equal`, but none of the [parameters](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.html) seem to work to ignore column names.

Answer (score 4):

`pd.DataFrame` is built around `pd.Series`, so it's unlikely you will be able to perform comparisons without column names.

But the most efficient way would be to drop down to `numpy`:

```
assert_equal = (df.values == df_equal.values).all()
```

To deal with `np.nan`, you can use `np.testing.assert_equal` and catch `AssertionError`, [as suggested by @Avaris](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710328/comparing-numpy-arrays-containing-nan) :

```
import numpy as np

def nan_equal(a,b):
    try:
        np.testing.assert_equal(a,b)
    except AssertionError:
        return False
    return True

assert_equal = nan_equal(df.values, df_equal.values)
```

Answer (score 2):

I just needed to get the values (numpy array) from the data frame, so the column names won't be considered.

```
df.eq(df_equal.values).all().all()
```

I would still like to see a parameter on `equals`, or `assert_frame_equal`. Maybe I am missing something.

---

An advantage of this compared to @jpp answer is that, I can get see which columns do not match, calling only `all()` only once:

```
df.eq(df_diff.values).all()
Out[24]: 
A     True
B    False
dtype: bool
```

---

One problem is that when eq is used, then **`np.nan` is not equal to `np.nan`**, in which case the following expression, would serve well:

```
(df.eq(df_equal.values) | (df.isnull().values & df_equal.isnull().values)).all().all()
```

Comment: Seems too crude to me, as .values will force casting into one type.

Answer (score 0):

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})

for i in range(df1.shape[0]):
    for j in range(df1.shape[1]):
        print(df1.iloc[i, j] == df2.iloc[i, j])
```

Will return:

```
True
True
True
True
```

Same thing for:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
```

One obvious issue is that column names matters in Pandas to sort dataframes. For example:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'b': [3, 4]})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2], 'B': [3, 4]})
print(df1)
print(df2)
```

renders as ('B' is before 'a' in df2):

```
   a  b
0  1  3
1  2  4
   B  a
0  3  1
1  4  2
```