# Does numpy's assert_array_equal verify that complex NaNs are exactly equal?

Tags: numpy

I want whether two numpy arrays with complex numbers containing `NaN` are exactly equal.

Specifically, I want to verify that for `NaN`, not only is there a `NaN` in both arrays but also that the real and imaginary part of the `NaN` match in value.

Does anybody know whether `assert_array_equal` does this or do I have to check this myself?

Comment: It would help if you provided an example.

Comment: This seems like something it would be easy to test at a prompt. For me, `np.testing.assert_array_equal(np.array([complex(2.3, np.nan)]), np.array([complex(np.nan, 2.3)]))` doesn't raise.

Comment: @MarkDickinson Of course! Should have thought of that myself... Many thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Numpy just checks whether there are `NaN` values [in the same positions](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/d9b1e32cb8ef90d6b4a47853241db2a28146a57d/numpy/testing/_private/utils.py#L720) and uses `np.isnan` for that purpose. Here it doesn't matter whether the real or imaginary part contains the NaN value:

```
>>> np.isnan(np.sqrt(-1.) + 1j)
True
>>> np.isnan(np.sqrt(-1.) * 1j)
True
```

Similarly for two arrays `a` and `b`:

```
>>> a = np.zeros(3, dtype=np.complex128)
>>> b = a.copy()
>>> a[0] = np.sqrt(-1.) + 1j
>>> b[0] = np.sqrt(-1.) * 1j
>>> a
array([nan+1.j,  0.+0.j,  0.+0.j])
>>> b
array([nan+nanj,  0. +0.j,  0. +0.j])
>>> np.testing.assert_array_equal(a, b) is None
True
```

Answer (score 2):

From [comparing numpy arrays containing NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710328/comparing-numpy-arrays-containing-nan)

```
def eq(a, b):
    return np.all((a == b) | (np.isnan(a) & np.isnan(b)))
```

To compare complex numbers just check the equality of real and imaginary parts. For example:

```
a = np.array([1+2j, 3+4j, np.nan+6j])
b = np.array([1+2j, 3+4j, np.nan+5j])

eq(a.real, b.real) & eq(a.imag, b.imag)
False
```

Edit: Or you can use `np.allclose(a.real, b.real, equal_nan=True) & np.allclose(a.imag, b.imag, equal_nan=True)`.