# NaN in pandas Series.tolist() behaves differently from NaN in list

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Why does

```
>> import pandas as pd
>> import numpy as np

>> list(pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 2])) == [np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 2]
```

return `False`? I get the same result with `pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 2]).tolist()`. I was trying to count the most common element in a pandas groupby object (so basically, a pandas Series) through the following function

```
def get_most_common(srs):
    """
    Returns the most common value in a list. For ties, it returns whatever
    value collections.Counter.most_common(1) gives.
    """
    from collections import Counter

    x = list(srs)
    my_counter = Counter(x)
    most_common_value = my_counter.most_common(1)[0][0]

    return most_common_value
```

and just realized that I get wrong counts for multiple NaNs even if I have a step `x = list(srs)`.

EDIT:
Just to clarify why this is an issue for me:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> Counter(pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2, 1, 5]).tolist())
Counter({nan: 1, nan: 1, nan: 1, 2.0: 2, 1.0: 1, 5.0: 1}) # each nan is counted differently
>>> Counter([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2, 1, 5])
Counter({nan: 3, 2: 2, 1: 1, 5: 1}) # nan count of 3 is correct
```

Comment: Not sure if I understood your question.  Is it not faster to do `df.groupby('some col').count()` instead?

Comment: Hi @r.ook I edited my question above to clarify why this is an issue for me

Comment: I understood *that part* of the question - and that's already answered.  `nan != nan` so you can't quite handle it that way.  As for the example in your clarification, try using `list(map(id, ...))` instead of `Counter`, you'll see why.  The object reference is the same in the `list`, but when the `pd.Series` is created the `np.nan` are treated as different objects.  What I am curious about is what are you actually trying to accomplish, because right now it sounds like an X-Y problem to me.

Comment: @r.ook so what pandas does is to have a different reference for each NaN, while for lists, it's the same reference? Is that correct? Which is why converting the Series to a list doesn't convert all the NaNs to the same reference?

Comment: That's right.  If you run `pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2, 1, 5]).apply(id)` you'll see the reference is already different inside the `Series`, so converting using `to_list()` will carry the difference.  It seems the reason is builtin `list` uses the imported `np.nan` object reference directly, whereas pandas create its own copy of the objects for its `Series` - which makes sense for them to be different since `nan != nan`.  Hence why it's more important to understand what you're trying to do instead of pigeonholing on the `nan` comparisons.

Comment: @r.ook if you can write this as an answer, I'd be very happy to accept it. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, I'll summarize my comments into an answer, make for easier reading. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The root issue, as @emilaz already stated, is that `nan != nan` in all cases.  However, the object reference is what matters in your observation.

Observe the following object references between `list` and `pd.Series`:

```
>>> s = pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2, 1, 5])
>>> s.apply(id)
0    149706480
1    202463472
2    202462336
3    149706912
4    149706288
5    149708784
6    149707200
dtype: int64

>>> l = [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2, 1, 5]
>>> list(map(id, l))
[68634768, 68634768, 68634768, 1389126848, 1389126848, 1389126832, 1389126896]
```

The `np.nan` object shares the same reference as the imported `np.nan` object in `list`, whereas a new reference is created for each `Series` (which makes sense for `pandas` usage).

The answer therefore is not to compare `nan` in such fashion.  `pandas` have its own ways to deal with `nan`, so depending on your actual activity, there may be a much simpler answer (e.g. `df.groupby('some col').count()`) than you envisioned.

Comment: Is it not faster for `srs.mode(dropna=False)`? I got `nan` as expected and much simpler.

Comment: I deleted my previous comment. It was wrong. But pd.Series.mode is too slow for me. Hmm.

Comment: How slow is too slow though? I'm not sure if there's a faster method since it's already vectorized IIRC.

Comment: I'm trying to have an if-else condition where I use `srs.mode` when NaN is present and `Counter` otherwise. I've been unsuccessful though, even `srs.isnull().values.any()` is taking too much time.

Comment: That's why I said it's an X-Y problem.  It's better to just post what you are trying to do as a new question and get that answered there.  Let others weigh in how you should take care of `nan`, because it doesn't seem your approach is getting the result you want.

Comment: Also to be more specific - with `pandas`, you should always try to use the relevant pandas methods instead of relying on external modules/methods as the former will almost always be faster.

Comment: Thanks. Maybe it deserves another question indeed.

Comment: I posted another question plus my attempt. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61105953/fastest-way-to-get-the-mode-of-a-pandas-series-with-nan

Answer (score 2):

In python, equating to nan always returns False. So the following behavior is expected:

```
import numpy as np
np.nan == np.nan
>>>> False
```

Which is why your list comparisons return False.

A possible workaround would be this:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

foo= list(pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 2]))
bar= [np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 2]

np.allclose(foo,bar, equal_nan=True)
>>>> True
```

This might interest you: [comparing numpy arrays containing NaN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10710328/comparing-numpy-arrays-containing-nan).

For finding the most common element, I'd suggest using pandas and the `value_counts()` method:

```
pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 2]).value_counts()
>>>> 2.0  2
```

If you care about nan counts, you can simply pass `dropna=False` to the method:

```
pd.Series([np.nan, np.nan, 2, np.nan, 2]).value_counts()
>>>> NaN  3
     2.0  2
```

Comment: Thanks. My concern though is that it causes a bug in my function. I've rewritten it to be `return srs.value_counts(dropna=False, sort=True, ascending=False).index[0])` though I'm not sure if this is the fastest way to do it. It gives the correct results though.

Comment: I had previously tested this function on `[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 2, 2]` and it gives the right results (my fault, but still...it's annoying).

Comment: I'd personally go with the np.allclose method, as it's the most readable and intuitive method for readers. If you come back to your code in two months (or someone else for that matter) you won't know what that line of code exactly does and if it's working correctly.

Comment: see my edit for an answer to your counting question.

Comment: I added an edit to clarify why this is an issue for me. Basically, converting the Series to a list is not equivalent to having a list. The `==` vs. `np.allclose` isn't that important: it's obvious from my bug that the np.nan behaves differently somehow from each other in the Series. The question though is why using Counter with a list is not the same as using Counter on a Series converted to a list.